# Windows 10: sfc and dism cannot repair corruption

Tags: windows-10, dism, sfc

There are several posts along this line, but the fixes that answered other questions did not solve my problem.

- Windows 10 Pro

  - Upgraded from W7 Pro, then did a "Reset", as I was having some problems with a screen saver and wanted to get a cleaner install without reformatting
- `sfc /scannow` found corruption found, but could not repair `malgunbd.ttf` [`CBS.log` below]

  - I then tried various `DISM` commands, first specifying no source, then a `/Source`:

    ```powershell
    Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:"D:\sources\install.wim"

      Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
      Version: 10.0.10240.16384

      Details for image : d:\sources\install.wim

        Index : 1
        Name : Windows 10 Pro
        Description : Windows 10 Pro
        Size : 13,736,528,128 bytes

      The operation completed successfully.
    ```

    ```powershell
    Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:"D:\sources\install.wim":1 /LimitAccess

       Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
       Version: 10.0.10240.16384

       Image Version: 10.0.10240.16384

       [==========================100.0%==========================]

         Error: 0x800f081f
           The source files could not be found.

           Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature.
           For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077

       The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
    ```

    - The source above is a recently downloaded ISO from MS, and I also tried a `.cab` file downloaded by one of the posters here, but it did not seem to contain the relevant font files.
  - I tried replacing `malgunbd.ttf` with the same font file from another W10 computer on which `sfc /scannow` runs without error, which did no good *(makes me wonder if the database `SFC` uses to determine whether system files are valid is itself corrupted)*

    - I understand that with W10, a repair/reinstall can be done that will just replace the system files, leaving previously installed programs, settings, and data undisturbed, but it seems overkill if the problem is just a single font file.

---

#### Logs

- **`cbs.log`:**

  ```powershell
  2015-09-23 21:00:12, Info  CSI   000050ad [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"malgunbd.ttf" of Microsoft-Windows-Font-TrueType-MalgunGothicBold, Version = 10.0.10240.16384, pA = amd64, nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch
  2015-09-23 21:00:12, Info  CSI   000050b0 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"malgunbd.ttf" of Microsoft-Windows-Font-TrueType-MalgunGothicBold, Version = 10.0.10240.16384, pA = amd64, nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch
  2015-09-23 21:00:12, Info  CSI   000050b1 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:252{126}]"Microsoft-OneCore-Fonts-DesktopFonts-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10240.16384.aa769378d5daebe8af8c9f1c3efdd70e"
  2015-09-23 21:00:12, Info  CSI   000050b2 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:346{173}]"Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-windows~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10240.16384.Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-windows-Deployment"
  2015-09-23 21:00:12, Info  CSI   000050b5 [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file [ml:42{21},l:40{20}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\fonts"\[l:24{12}]"malgunbd.ttf"; source file in store is also corrupted
  2015-09-23 21:00:12, Info  CSI   000050b8 [SR] Repair complete
  2015-09-23 21:00:12, Info  CSI   000050b9 [SR] Committing transaction
  2015-09-23 21:00:12, Info  CSI   000050be [SR] Verify and Repair Transaction completed. All files and registry keys listed in this transaction  have been successfully repaired
  ```
- **`dism.log`:** *(no source specified)*

  ```powershell
  13:00:07, Info      DISM   DISM.EXE: <----- Starting Dism.exe session ----->
  13:00:07, Info      DISM   DISM.EXE:
  13:00:07, Info      DISM   DISM.EXE: Host machine information: OS Version=10.0.10240, Running architecture=amd64, Number of processors=8
  13:00:07, Info      DISM   DISM.EXE: Dism.exe version: 10.0.10240.16384

  13:00:07, Info      DISM   DISM.EXE: Executing command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\Dism.exe" /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

  13:00:08, Warning   DISM   DISM OS Provider: PID=1912 TID=9724 Unable to set the DLL search path to the servicing stack folder. C:\Windows may not point to a valid Windows folder. - CDISMOSServiceManager::Final_OnConnect

  13:00:08, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1912 TID=9724 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
  13:00:08, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1912 TID=9724 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Temp\D205D094-AE23-4DDE-9CF0-828A4790B1F2\PEProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
  13:00:08, Warning   DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1912 TID=9724 Failed to Load the provider: C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Temp\D205D094-AE23-4DDE-9CF0-828A4790B1F2\PEProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)
  13:00:08, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1912 TID=9724 Failed to get and initialize the PE Provider.  Continuing by assuming that it is not a WinPE image. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect
  13:00:08, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1912 TID=9724 Finished initializing the Provider Map. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect
  13:00:08, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1912 TID=9724 Getting Provider DISMLogger - CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider
  13:00:08, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1912 TID=9724 Provider has previously been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider

  13:00:08, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1912 TID=9724 Getting Provider OSServices - CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider
  13:00:08, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1912 TID=9724 Provider has previously been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider

  13:00:09, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1912 TID=9724 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
  13:00:09, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1912 TID=9724 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Temp\D205D094-AE23-4DDE-9CF0-828A4790B1F2\Wow64provider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
  13:00:09, Warning   DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1912 TID=9724 Failed to get the IDismObject Interface - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider(hr:0x80004002)
  13:00:09, Warning   DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1912 TID=9724 Failed to Load the provider: C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Temp\D205D094-AE23-4DDE-9CF0-828A4790B1F2\Wow64provider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x80004002)
  13:00:09, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1912 TID=9724 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
  13:00:09, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1912 TID=9724 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Temp\D205D094-AE23-4DDE-9CF0-828A4790B1F2\SmiProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
  13:00:09, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1912 TID=9724 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Temp\D205D094-AE23-4DDE-9CF0-828A4790B1F2\SmiProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
  13:00:09, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1912 TID=9724 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
  13:00:09, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1912 TID=9724 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
  13:00:09, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1912 TID=9724 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Temp\D205D094-AE23-4DDE-9CF0-828A4790B1F2\EmbeddedProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
  13:00:09, Warning   DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=1912 TID=9724 Failed to Load the provider: C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Temp\D205D094-AE23-4DDE-9CF0-828A4790B1F2\EmbeddedProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)

  13:00:09, Info      DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=1912 TID=9724 CBS session options=0x48100! - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
  13:03:08, Info      DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=1912 TID=1900  Error in operation: source for package or file not found, ResolveSource() unsuccessful. (CBS HRESULT=0x800f081f) - CCbsConUIHandler::Error
  13:03:08, Error     DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=1912 TID=9724 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x800f081f)
  13:03:08, Error     DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=1912 TID=9724 The source files could not be found; their location must be specified using the /source option to restore the feature. - GetCbsErrorMsg
  13:03:08, Error     DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=1912 TID=9724 Failed processing package changes with session option CbsSessionOptionRepairStoreCorruption - CDISMPackageManager::RestoreHealth(hr:0x800f081f)
  13:03:08, Error     DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=1912 TID=9724 The source files could not be found; their location must be specified using the /source option to restore the feature. - GetCbsErrorMsg
  13:03:08, Error     DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=1912 TID=9724 Failed to restore the image health. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ProcessCmdLine_CleanupImage(hr:0x800f081f)
  13:03:08, Error     DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=1912 TID=9724 Failed while processing command cleanup-image. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x800f081f)
  13:03:08, Info      DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=1912 TID=9724 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine

  13:03:08, Info      DISM   DISM.EXE: Image session has been closed. Reboot required=no.
  13:03:08, Info      DISM   DISM.EXE:
  13:03:08, Info      DISM   DISM.EXE: <----- Ending Dism.exe session ----->
  ```
- **`dism.log`:** *(source: `install.wim`)*

  ```powershell
  13:06:20, Info      DISM   DISM.EXE: <----- Starting Dism.exe session ----->
  13:06:20, Info      DISM   DISM.EXE:
  13:06:20, Info      DISM   DISM.EXE: Host machine information: OS Version=10.0.10240, Running architecture=amd64, Number of processors=8
  13:06:20, Info      DISM   DISM.EXE: Dism.exe version: 10.0.10240.16384

  13:06:20, Info      DISM   DISM.EXE: Executing command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\Dism.exe" /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:C:\users\ron\downloads\Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-base~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10240.16384.cab

  13:06:21, Warning   DISM   DISM OS Provider: PID=12608 TID=11328 Unable to set the DLL search path to the servicing stack folder. C:\Windows may not point to a valid Windows folder. - CDISMOSServiceManager::Final_OnConnect

  13:06:21, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12608 TID=11328 Attempting to initialize the logger from the Image Session. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect
  13:06:21, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12608 TID=11328 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
  13:06:21, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12608 TID=11328 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Temp\BD1F1F9B-95B3-41C0-9336-5F3CD9D0A587\LogProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
  13:06:21, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12608 TID=11328 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Temp\BD1F1F9B-95B3-41C0-9336-5F3CD9D0A587\LogProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
  13:06:21, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12608 TID=11328 Found and Initialized the DISM Logger. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_InitializeLogger
  13:06:21, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12608 TID=11328 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
  13:06:21, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12608 TID=11328 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Temp\BD1F1F9B-95B3-41C0-9336-5F3CD9D0A587\PEProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
  13:06:21, Warning   DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12608 TID=11328 Failed to Load the provider: C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Temp\BD1F1F9B-95B3-41C0-9336-5F3CD9D0A587\PEProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)
  13:06:21, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12608 TID=11328 Failed to get and initialize the PE Provider.  Continuing by assuming that it is not a WinPE image. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect
  13:06:21, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12608 TID=11328 Finished initializing the Provider Map. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect

  13:06:21, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12608 TID=11328 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
  13:06:21, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12608 TID=11328 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Temp\BD1F1F9B-95B3-41C0-9336-5F3CD9D0A587\UnattendProvider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
  13:06:21, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12608 TID=11328 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Temp\BD1F1F9B-95B3-41C0-9336-5F3CD9D0A587\UnattendProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
  13:06:21, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12608 TID=11328 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
  13:06:21, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12608 TID=11328 Provider has not previously been encountered.  Attempting to initialize the provider. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
  13:06:21, Info      DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12608 TID=11328 Loading Provider from location C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Temp\BD1F1F9B-95B3-41C0-9336-5F3CD9D0A587\Wow64provider.dll - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
  13:06:21, Warning   DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12608 TID=11328 Failed to get the IDismObject Interface - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider(hr:0x80004002)
  13:06:21, Warning   DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=12608 TID=11328 Failed to Load the provider: C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Temp\BD1F1F9B-95B3-41C0-9336-5F3CD9D0A587\Wow64provider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x80004002)

  13:06:22, Info      DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12608 TID=11328 Processing the top level command token(cleanup-image). - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ValidateCmdLine
  13:06:22, Info      DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12608 TID=11328 Attempting to route to appropriate command handler. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
  13:06:22, Info      DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12608 TID=11328 Routing the command... - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
  13:06:22, Warning   DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12608 TID=11328 CBS AddSource failed with HRESULT=0x8007007b! - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
  13:06:22, Info      DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12608 TID=11328 CBS session options=0x48100! - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
  13:08:52, Info      DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12608 TID=11404  Error in operation: source for package or file not found, ResolveSource() unsuccessful. (CBS HRESULT=0x800f081f) - CCbsConUIHandler::Error
  13:08:52, Error     DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12608 TID=11328 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x800f081f)
  13:08:52, Error     DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12608 TID=11328 The source files could not be found; their location must be specified using the /source option to restore the feature. - GetCbsErrorMsg
  13:08:52, Error     DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12608 TID=11328 Failed processing package changes with session option CbsSessionOptionRepairStoreCorruption - CDISMPackageManager::RestoreHealth(hr:0x800f081f)
  13:08:52, Error     DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12608 TID=11328 The source files could not be found; their location must be specified using the /source option to restore the feature. - GetCbsErrorMsg
  13:08:52, Error     DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12608 TID=11328 Failed to restore the image health. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ProcessCmdLine_CleanupImage(hr:0x800f081f)
  13:08:52, Error     DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12608 TID=11328 Failed while processing command cleanup-image. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x800f081f)
  13:08:52, Info      DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=12608 TID=11328 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine

  13:08:52, Info      DISM   DISM Manager: PID=11312 TID=9104 Closing session event handle 0x190 - CDISMManager::CloseImageSession
  13:08:52, Info      DISM   DISM.EXE: Image session has been closed. Reboot required=no.
  13:08:52, Info      DISM   DISM.EXE:
  13:08:52, Info      DISM   DISM.EXE: <----- Ending Dism.exe session ----->
  ```

Comment: copy the font file from another W10 pc?

Comment: @Moab I mentioned in my post I had already tried that.  That is why I wonder if there is a problem in the sfc database.

Comment: So the problem is down to the source files could not be found error?

Comment: Why are you worried about font files, they wouldn't cause any problems, I remember there being an update that caused this harmless error.

Comment: @Moab  That seems to be the case

Comment: @Ramhound So your advice would be to just ignore this error in a system font. Which update caused this error?  and why isn't everyone having the problem?

Comment: Everyone with the update in question is having the problem.  I just recall there being an update that caused this problem I don't recall which specific update it was

Comment: @Ramhound Hmm.  Hard to believe without more data.  I have 4 W10 machines, all of which download updates automatically, and only one of which has the problem.

Comment: The font in question isn't even a system font.  ["It is not a system font.  I just checked the ISO and my computer and it is design for the Korean language"](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:V-nFUnFe98YJ:answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/sfc-cannot-fix-corrupt-font-file/7775bedc-9537-4573-aadb-4a86740ee1fa+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&safe=active).  I just know for a fact, there was an update released for Windows 10 that causes this problem with font files, the error for that reason, can be ignored.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29641/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-ramhound).

Comment: What happens if the font is removed?

Comment: @Moab SFC tries to repair it, fails, and returns the error message.

Comment: Time to ignore that problem.

Comment: @Moab The issue with that is that whenever I run SFC, I would then have to examine CBS.log to see if the problem is this one, or a new problem.

Comment: Question is, is that harder than fixing the issue.

Comment: @Moab It's easier than a re-format / clean install.  But I'm hoping someone knowledgeable will be able to help me with a less intrusive method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to repair my Windows installation such that `SFC` returned a normal result.

Using a freshly downloaded USB image of W10, I did an inplace upgrade as suggested in `magicandre1981`'s comments.

After that, there was a different file that was corrupt and could not be repaired.

Again, `DISM` did not initially repair this.  However, I was able to determine that the file in question was located in the `C:\windows\winsxs` and also the `C:\windows\system32` folders.

Since the previous installation did not flag that file as corrupt, I figured I could use the previous installations copy of that file as a good file.

Before running DISM again, I executed the following from an elevated command prompt and then re-booted the machine, as per instructions in an article at `thewindowsclub.com` which is not presently accessible.  I'm not sure if the reboot is necessary, as that is not mentioned in another article.

```
net stop wuauserv
cd %systemroot%\SoftwareDistribution
ren Download Download.old
net start wuauserv
net stop bits
net start bits
net stop cryptsvc
cd %systemroot%\system32
ren catroot2 catroot2old
net start cryptsvc
```

By running DISM, and using `c:\windows.old\windows\winsxs`  as the Source, I was able to repair the store.  And then running SFC resulted in the original file being repaired.

Why this is happening, I have no idea.  On a different machine, (and different internet connection/ISP) the upgraded (from W7) W10 installation also showed a corrupt file when running SFC.  On that machine, DISM was able to repair it using the default Windows Update as a source.

Comment: This [answer](https://superuser.com/q/1579030/529800) will provide more depth to understand why

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

The the DISM.log I see this error:

```
AddSource failed with HRESULT=0x8007007b! 
Error in operation: source for package or file not found, ResolveSource() unsuccessful.
```

Error `0x8007007b` means `ERROR_INVALID_NAME`:

```
C:\>err 0x8007007b
# for hex 0x8007007b / decimal -2147024773
  STIERR_INVALID_DEVICE_NAME                                     stierr.h
# as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), FACILITY_WIN32 (0x7), Code 0x7b
# for hex 0x7b / decimal 123
  ERROR_INVALID_NAME                                             winerror.h
# The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is
# incorrect.
# 2 matches found for "0x8007007b"
```

Make sure the drive D: is really your DVD/mounted ISO drive.

I extracted the 2 packages into .cab files and uploaded them to my OneDrive.

Download and extract both into C:\Source:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ijpex5tax011ved/Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-windows~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10240.16384.cab?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/588ka8pv7uai2he/Microsoft-OneCore-Fonts-DesktopFonts-windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10240.16384.cab?dl=0

And now run this command:

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:C:\Source
```

Does this work?

Comment: Thank you for looking at that so closely.  I will edit my question to show how I confirmed the validity of the file path

Comment: I posted a 2nd solution. try this

Comment: Thanks. Out of town for a few days now. Will try your solution when I get back Thu or Fri.

Comment: Gave it a try.  Unfortunately, the same error message as before.  [Here is the dism log](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8EDB73C8A1A37A69!559&authkey=!ANlsEcgxujKxLHY&ithint=file%2clog) for that event

Comment: I also need the current CBS.log to see more.

Comment: Thank you again for looking at this.  Not being certain exactly what you wanted, I re-ran both SFC and DISM (with the above DISM command referencing the extracted CAB files you supplied above); and ZIP'd them into a single compressed file [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8EDB73C8A1A37A69!562&authkey=!ADh9MDyDW30k8WI&ithint=file%2czip)

Comment: I can't see why the file is not found, only that it is not found. Repair Windows via inplace upgrade: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html

Comment: I did the refresh once before, after doing the upgrade to W10 from W7.  On that occasion I elected to NOT preserve my installed programs, and had to re-install them all.  I think I'll try the option to keep my programs, and see if that will work.  Thanks for trying.

Comment: the refresh from Windows will kill desktop programs, but the Inplace upgrade keeps them installed.