# What is the purpose of the DISM /RestoreHealth parameter and SFC?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8, dism, sfc

What is the purpose of the `DISM` `/RestoreHealth` parameter and the `SFC` `/ScanNow` parameter?

- How do they correlate to one another?
- In what order should they be run?
- Why does the order sequence matter when executing either?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [Component Store](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/manage-the-component-store) [`%WinDir%\WinSxS`] maintains a backup copy of all Windows system files, and [`SFC`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sfc) [**S**ystem **F**ile **C**hecker] & [`DISM`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-operating-system-package-servicing-command-line-options) [**D**eployment **I**mage **S**ervicing and **M**anagement] manage two separate, vital pieces of the Component Store and OS, with `SFC` relying *entirely* upon what `DISM` manages:

- `DISM` has two functions `SFC` relies upon, `/StartComponentCleanup` and `/RestoreHealth`, with `/RestoreHealth` relying solely upon `/StartComponentCleanup`

  - **[`/StartComponentCleanup`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder#dismexe):** [Cleans](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder) the Component Store of any broken [hard links](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/manage-the-component-store#hard-links) 
     *(It's imperative folks on Insider Builds run this regularly due to the frequent updates)*
  - **[`/RestoreHealth`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/repair-a-windows-image):**  Verifies and fixes any corruption in the Component Store by verifying it's system file backups against known good copies from the Windows Update servers through hash comparison; while an offline method does exist [below], it may not always fix the corruption

    - ***Windows 7:** [SUR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/deployment/fix-windows-update-errors#resolution-for-windows-7-service-pack-1-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1) [**S**ystem **U**pdate **R**eadiness] tool is used in lieu of this, as `DISM` didn't have this functionality until Windows 8, with SUR operating differently than `DISM`*
- ***`SFC` always assumes the Component Store is not corrupted*** and is why the `DISM` `/RestoreHealth` parameter should always be run prior to `SFC`; not doing so allows a corrupted Component Store to potentially replace a good system file with a corrupted one or fail to fix corruption within `%WinDir%` altogether

  - **[`/ScanNow`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sfc):** Verifies and fixes any corruption within `%WinDir%` by verifying against the known good copies within the Component Store through hash comparison

`SFC` and `DISM` *will not* resolve hardware related issues, as they only resolve OS system file corruption, excluding Registry hives and user config files within `%WinDir%\System32\drivers\etc`.

---

**`DISM` and `SFC` [must](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e) be executed in the order listed:** 
 <sup>*(Each relies upon what the preceding does; if Windows 7: skip to #3)*</sup>

1. <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → *Open*: `PowerShell` → <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+OK

   ```powershell
   # Windows ≥8:
     # Online [booted to Windows]:
       Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup

     # Offline [mounted WIM, possibly when booted to a different Windows install]:
       Dism /Image:"Z:\Windows" /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
   ```

   The Component Store should always be [cleaned](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder) prior to running Windows Update, after an issue with Windows Update, and at least once a month, as it becomes dirty over time from updates occasionally breaking [hard links](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/manage-the-component-store#hard-links).
2. ```powershell
   # Windows ≥8:
     # Online [booted to Windows]:
       Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

     # Offline [mounted WIM, or when booted to WinPE/WinRE or different Windows install]:
       Dism /Image:"Z:\Windows" /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
   ```

   Requires an internet connection, else the offline method will be required:

   - Use the `install.<esd|wim>` from the [Windows Install ISO](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-installation-media-for-windows-99a58364-8c02-206f-aa6f-40c3b507420d)  for the installed version:

     1. *Create Windows <#> installation media* → *Download tool now* → *install on another PC*
     2. Mount ISO to determine installed OS [index](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#get-imageinfo) [image] from its `install.<esd|wim>`:

        ```powershell
        Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:"Z:\sources\install.<esd|wim>"
        ```
     3. Specify index number at the end of the [`/Source`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-a-windows-repair-source) parameter:

        ```powershell
        # Online [booted to Windows]:
          # ESD:
            Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:esd:"Z:\sources\install.esd":6 /LimitAccess

          # WIM:
            Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:"Z:\sources\install.wim":6 /LimitAccess

        # Offline [mounted WIM, or when booted to WinPE/WinRE or different Windows install]:
          Dism /Image:"Z:\Windows" /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:esd:"Z:\sources\install.esd":6 /LimitAccess
        ```
3. **Windows 7:** Run the [SUR tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/deployment/fix-windows-update-errors#resolution-for-windows-7-service-pack-1-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1)
4. Reboot; if errors are found, review `%WinDir%\Logs\DISM\dism.log` from the bottom up 
    <sup>*(Log files are easier to read and sift through via the [Log syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30776845/6819406) in [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/))*</sup>

   - **Windows ≥8:** `%WinDir%\Logs\DISM\dism.log`
   - **Windows 7:** `%WinDir%\Logs\CBS\CheckSUR.log` 
      <sup>*([How to fix SUR errors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/deployment/fix-windows-update-errors#how-to-fix-errors-that-are-found-in-the-checksur-log-file))*</sup>
5. ```bash
   # Online [booted to Windows]:
     Sfc /ScanNow

   # Offline [booted to WinPE/WinRE or different Windows install]:
     Sfc /ScanNow /OffBootDir=Z:\ /OffWinDir=Z:\Windows
     # C: is usually not the drive letter in WinPE/WinRE
     # To ascertain: DiskPart → Lis Vol → Exit
   ```
6. Reboot; if errors are found, output to `%UserProfile%\Desktop\SFCdetails.log` and [review](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/analyze-sfc-program-log-file-entries):

   ```powershell
   # Cmd:
     FindStr /c:"[SR]" "%WinDir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log" > "%UserProfile%\Desktop\SFCdetails.log"

   # PowerShell:
     FindStr /c:"[SR]" "$env:WinDir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log" > "$env:UserProfile\Desktop\SFCdetails.log"
   ```

---

I run these weekly via [Task Scheduler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/about-the-task-scheduler) to help prevent random issues from occurring:

1. [`Dism_ComponentCleanup.xml`](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/Task%20Scheduler/Dism_ComponentCleanup.xml) 
    *Executes weekly on Sundays at 11:30:00*
2. [`Dism_RestoreHealth.xml`](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/Task%20Scheduler/Dism_RestoreHealth.xml) 
    *Executes weekly on Sundays at 12:00:00*
3. [`Sfc_ScanNow.xml`](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/Task%20Scheduler/Sfc_ScanNow.xml) 
    *Executes weekly on Sundays at 13:00:00*

**Import into Task Scheduler:**

- **GUI:**

  1. **<kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>** → Open: `TaskSchd.msc`
  2. *Action* → *New Folder...* → Name: `Custom`
  3. *Action* → *Import Task...* → `<task_name>.xml`
- **CLI:**

  - **[`Cmd`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks):**

    ```powershell
    SchTasks /Create /Xml "%UserProfile%\Downloads\<task_name>.xml" /Tn "\Custom\Task Name" /Ru "%ComputerName%\%UserName%"
    ```
  - **[`Powershell`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/register-scheduledtask):**

    ```powershell
    Register-ScheduledTask -Xml (Get-Content '$env:UserProfile\Downloads\<task_name>.xml' | Out-String) -TaskName "Task Name" -TaskPath "\Custom\" -User $env:ComputerName\$env:UserName –Force
    ```

Comment: The section on StartComponentCleanup appears to be useful on my Windows Insider machine that is having some issue with the latest build.

Comment: Running StartComponentCleanup against the C:\Windows directory (which I checked with diskpart is the correct drive letter) fails and it logs that C:\Windows is not a WIM mount point. I'm running WinPE off a usb. What might the issue be?

Comment: @pingOfDoom I need to do some research, as I'm getting errors on my end using `/RestoreHealth`, so either something changed or I overlooked a step since I use a custom-built WinRE/WinPE image and a standalone `dism.exe` from the ADK.

Comment: This is an AWESOME POST  but I have yet to see any of these tools fix anything whatsoever and I have been doing this a long time.  (I originally used the SFC tool in Win2K.. where it came from).  I have however wasted hours and hours of my time using them.  I would love to hear from anyone EVER that found a solution by using them.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I'm not understanding the premise of the question - these commands fix corruption within the Component Store/system files, and when corruption is found and fixed, the output of the command and the `CBS.log` will detail what was replaced. If no corruption exists [hashes match], then corruption isn't the issue. To see what that looks like, please see the Review link or rename/delete a system file within `%WinDir%`, perform steps 5 & 6, and review the log output [or] _(I wouldn't recommend the same with `%WinDir%\WinSxS` since it's not intended to be directly accessed by users)_.

Comment: I completely get what you are saying @JW0914.. I also completely understand what these commands do.  In the many MANY years I have been fixing computers, I have yet to se either of these commands fix anything.  I am not saying that they don't work.. I am saying the problem is 99.9999% "somewhere else".  In my experience, it is usually profile corruption dealing with the registry.. sometimes it is in a 3rd party filter that these commands can't fix.  Also.. I kid not, this was a great post but I don't want people to think that this will likely fix their problems. It might.. but probably won't.

Comment: BTW, I still +1 you. :)  I just see SFC and DISM come up over and over and in all of my years, they have fixed nothing.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I understand where you're coming from, as most issues will not be a result of system file corruption, although most users will benefit from running `/StartComponentCleanup` and `/RestoreHealth` regularly, as a dirty Component Store will cause issues with Windows Update, Add/Remove Features, etc. _(the Component Store is how Windows is serviced and where drivers are backed up to prior to a bi-annual update)_, and while Microsoft doesn't recommend running `/StartComponentCleanup` prior to `/RestoreHealth`, I do since a dirty Component Store will often cause `/RestoreHealth` to fail

Comment: @JW0914 - In step 1, `Dism ... /StartComponentCleanup`, "previous versions of updated components will be immediately deleted (without a 30 day grace period)". I'm concerned that this introduces the risk of not being able to roll back an update in case of a problem with one. (Quote is from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder?view=windows-11#dismexe)

Comment: @NewSites Please see the first and second links under #1. #2 and #5 are the important ones to fix your issue from your Question. If hard links are broken with the Component Store, #2 will fail, which is why #1 is there and man page links listed throughout. If #2 fails, it's almost always due to broken hard links within the Component Store and#1 is required to fix that. Rolling back a KB update is something only a tiny percentage of users will ever do, but is why man page links are listed throughout that fully explain what occurs with #1. It's not a requirement, only #2 & #5 is