# Could not download or delete files on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Two days ago, my computer suddenly could not download any files from any browsers and also I could not delete any files unless I drag the files inside the recycle bin.

I've tried so many tools like MalwareBytes, CCleaner,  Registry Fixers, and so on but nothing fixes that. I am not sure whether it is because of some registry error or virus/malware? I've also checked Windows Security and Firewall and none of those are issues as well. I don't want to reinstall the windows just for this and I don't think it is a proper solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Execute the following _in the order listed_ while connected to the internet: `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup`→ `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` → Reboot → `SFC /ScanNow` → Reboot. If issue isn't fxed, it will be more efficient to do a Repair Install vs troubleshooting, as it sounds like user profile corruption. To perform a Repair Install, [download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) the Win10 ISO, select Install on Another PC, extract ISO's contents to a folder and run `setup.exe`, while booted to Windows, choosing to Keep All Files.

Answer (score 0):

Question: Was the problem related to a recent Window Update?

Checks and fixes:

- `chkdsk`
- [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
- If System Restore is enabled, roll back to before the problem arrived
- At worst, do [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try with `chkdsk` and scannow. Sadly, I forgot to enable restore points for that PC.

Comment: Fix any error you find before continuing.

Comment: When performing system file repair, `SFC` is ran last, not first - sequence of commands should be: `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup`→ `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` → `SFC /ScanNow` ([explanation](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800))

Comment: @JW0914: I prefer SFC first, to know if something is wrong with the current setup. My link recommends DISM as second and then SFC again.

Comment: @harrymc That preference is the incorrect way of doing so, which I extensively explain in the link. A person is welcome to their own opinion, but shouldn't be encouraging others to do so incorrectly based upon such an opinion. _We've had this same exact conversation on at least on three separate occasions...  if wanting to recommend your opinion, please at least include the correct way of doing so, stating you prefer x over the correct y procedure._

Comment: @JW0914: Yes, we keep on coming back to it. Your method is certainly correct, but that doesn't mean that mine isn't. My order of things may show that the problem is indeed a corrupted local image. Also, in case of Windows corruption, DISM might not fix the problem but will change stuff, making it harder to analyze the current state of Windows. Your way is correct for fixing a problem that can be fixed with that method; my method is more oriented toward forensics. They are complementary, not contradictory.

Comment: It's not _my_ method, nor is it my _opinion_...  it's the factually correct way of doing so, per Microsoft Docs, _due to each command **exclusively** relying upon the preceding one_. It appears you simply refuse to fact check anything you're stating, please actually read the link in my previous comment, which explains in detail and shows why your perspective is _factually inaccurate_. Your perspective is analogous to stating 1+1=11, even though the facts dictate it equals two. [What is the purpose of the `DISM /RestoreHealth` parameter and `SFC`?](https://superuser.com/q/1579030/529800)