# I can't update to Windows 10 version 1909: error code 0x80073712, and resetting the computer still produces the error code

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1903

I'm running Windows 10 v1903 and I can't update to v1909, with it producing error `0x80073712`.

- The solutions I've found on thus far don't work, including Reseting Windows and reinstalling Windows 10, but it still produces that error code when I try to update Windows.
- Manually running Windows Update results in BSOD error `UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP` after the update reaches 10% - 15% complete

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: That error code means some component / driver is missing. Update BIOS and ALL drivers using the Manufacturer's Driver update app. Restart and try updating again

Comment: While @teckie_boy's answer is on the right path, please issue the following, _in the order listed_, while connected to the internet: `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup`  → `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` → Reboot → `Sfc /ScanNow` → Reboot → Retry update _(see [this](https://superuser.com/q/1579030/529800) answer for more information)_

Comment: See the link to the answer in my comment above, boot to WinRE and run the offline versions of those commands _(listed in the linked-to answer)_. Out of curiosity, why not just download the most recent Windows ISO via Microsoft's Windows Media Creation tool, extract the ISO, then run `setup.exe` while booted to Windows, choosing to keep all files and settings?

Comment: A Reset is not a Windows install, it resets the installed version back to OOBE using the Component Store [`%WinDir%\WinSxS`] in ≥v1809 _(in ≤v1803, it uses an `install.ed`/`install.wim`)_. Running an in-place upgrade by launching a Windows ISO's `setup.exe` while booted to Windows bypasses issues that can cause a version upgrade to fail via Windows Update _(if the ISO is the same version # as installed, it's a Repair Install)_. If @teckie_boy is correct about the BSOD being due to the Component Store, an in-place upgrade should work after running an offline `/StartComponentCleanup` from WinRE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115267/discussion-between-jw0914-and-the-tech-expert-guy).

Comment: @JW0914 I still can't perform minor updates (such as the 2020-10 Cumulative Update for .NET Framework for Windows 10 Update 2004 and the 2020-10 Security Update for Adobe Flash Player), and it's the same error code: 0x80073712. Do you know how to solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Please do the same thing I recommended [yesterday](https://superuser.com/questions/1590678/i-cant-update-to-windows-10-version-1909-error-code-0x80073712-and-resetting?noredirect=1#comment2431354_1590678). If you are unable to do so while booted to Windows, please boot to WinRE and use the steps in the answer I previously linked to run the offline commands, running them in the order listed [#1 - #5].

Comment: @TheTechExpertGuy Please use the chat link, as comments aren't for conversation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error code `0x80073712` means `ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT`:

1. <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd> → Type `cmd` → Run as administrator
2. ```powershell
   Sfc /ScanNow
   ```
3. ```powershell
   Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
   ```

If you get an error message after executing one of the commands, please update your question.

Comment: The commands are inversed, as `SFC` relies upon `/RestoreHealth` - for more information, see [this](https://superuser.com/q/1579030/529800) answer _(`/StartComponentCleanup` should also be run prior to executing `/RestoreHealth`)_

Answer (score 0):

The `Dism` command did not work for me, but this did (and it's much quicker), and usually `Sfc /ScanNow` is overkill and takes forever

1. (in cmd as admin type) `net stop wuauserv`
2. delete all contents of this folder (update are downloaded here, one of them could be corrupted):    
   `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download` (find and close the handles of the one you can't delete).
3. (in cmd) `net start wuauserv`
4. Set your sleep power setting to `never`, and let your pc run the whole night (some update need more than 8 hours of downloading)

Comment: You're misunderstanding what `Dism` and `Sfc` do - Windows Update relies upon the Component Store, which is what the `/Cleanup-Image` parameter manages _(I cover this in more depth [here](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800))_. The Windows Update Troubleshooter will kill & restart the Windows Update required services, however it doesn't initiate management of the component store, so if the Troubleshooter doesn't resolve an issue, it's always a good idea to rule out the Component Store by first cleaning it [`/StartComponentCleanup`], then checking for corruption within it [`/RestoreHealth`]

Comment: Thanks for your comment! You are right, I'm misunderstanding them. (And my solution did not work, I'm trying your)

Comment: I'm not sure if cleaning the Component Store and checking it for corruption before re-running Windows Update will work, but if not, at least that's been ruled out. Just to verify, are you receiving the exact same error number in the OP's question?

Comment: Yes I have the same error (0x80073712). And it did not work (`The source files could not be found`). But I just noticed it's an "optional quality update", so it might not fit on my PC.

Comment: Were you connected to the internet when you ran `/RestoreHealth`? If so, and `Dism` produced the source files error, perform a repair install of Windows

Comment: @JW0914 yes I was connected  to the internet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't have the problem anymore so I can't try it.