# Windows "lagging" after few minutes

Tags: windows, lag

yesteday I updated my windows and it started lagging after like 30 minutes of working. I never seen this before. It isnt like everything is lagging but, if I am watching like youtube or I am on discord or even in game everything is going all right, but if I go to my homescreen and click on the task manager, google,.. it starts lagging. My CPU and SSD,.. usage is on minumum like 30% max.
If you could reccomend anything I should try thanks forward.

I have Ryzen 3 1300X, 12GB RAM, 1060 6GB and SSD on which I have windows.

Comment: Please run the following _in the order listed_ and while connected to the internet: `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` → `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` → Reboot → `SFC /ScanNow` → Reboot _(see [this](https://superuser.com/q/1579030/529800) answer for more info)_. You may also want to run: `ChkDsk C: /OfflineScanAndFix`

Comment: I did all of this, I will see if it helps,..