# Windows 10 dark mode - icons minimize, maximize close not visible for some active windows

Tags: windows-10, gui, bug

On my windows 10 enterprise (Version 10.0.18363) the display of the icons to close, minimize or maximize a window are not consistent in dark mode.

In the left window all three icons are visible. On the right window you can see that the icons to minimize and close are not visible. Only the maximize icon is visible because the mouse pointer is hovering over the icon

- Expected: the three icons (minimize, maximize, close are always
  visible)
- Actual: for some windows the three icons are invisible in dark mode
  unless the mouse pointer hovers over them.

Desired Fix: adjust contrast of icon in dark mode if window is active (focused)

[image: windows 10 dark mode icons not visible].

1. Is anyone else affected by this?
2. Is it a bug or just something on  my box?

Comment: This sounds like either an issue with DWM _(Task Manager → Details → Right-click `dwm.exe` → End Task → End Process)_, else it's likely a user profile corruption issue; if so, the only fix is creating a new user profile _(use Windows' USMT to backup the user profile)_, however I would first try running the following in the order listed, and while connected to the internet: `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` → `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` → Reboot → `SFC /ScanNow` → Reboot _(see [this](https://superuser.com/q/1579030/529800) answer for more info)_.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I could not run `dism /Online`  because i do not have elevated privileges. On monday i try to get in contact with an admin to do this.