# Windows 10 File Explorer and other programs not responding properly and are really slow

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, freeze, crash

Whenever I open a folder, Explorer crashes or stops responding, sometimes with the screen going black with only a cursor, coupled with everything on my PC becoming really slow (deleting/copying takes longer than it should), and context menus take too long to render.

- I've had this issue for the last ten days and have tried `sfc /scannow`, with it stating

  ```
  Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them.

  For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at %windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. 
  For offline repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag.
  ```
- I even reset Wndows 10, keeping files, but it didn't resolve the issue: 
   [image: error image1] 
   [image: error image2]
- ```
  Details:

    Source
      Windows Explorer

    Summary
      Stopped responding and was closed

    Date
      ‎18-‎12-‎2020 09:44

    Status
      Report sent

    Description
      A problem caused this program to stop interacting with Windows.

    Faulting Application Path:      C:\Windows\explorer.exe
      Problem signature
        Problem Event Name:         AppHangB1
        Application Name:           explorer.exe
        Application Version:        10.0.18362.1171
        Application Timestamp:      d942099d
        Hang Signature:             1b8e
        Hang Type:                  134217728
        OS Version:                 10.0.18363.2.0.0.768.100
        Locale ID:                  16393

      Additional Hang Signature 1:  1b8eed153775311dc16d8b6ee7508253
      Additional Hang Signature 2:  4901
      Additional Hang Signature 3:  49015d652d0827ad983b953cdfe24a66
      Additional Hang Signature 4:  1b8e
      Additional Hang Signature 5:  1b8eed153775311dc16d8b6ee7508253
      Additional Hang Signature 6:  4901
      Additional Hang Signature 7:  49015d652d0827ad983b953cdfe24a66

      Extra information about the problem
        Bucket ID:                  26cbcd1ca30d218c27ea0b9e68d604ae (1723202582414230702)
  ```

How do I troubleshoot and fix this?

Comment: Does it behave the same way when you boot into [Safe Mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-10-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234)?

Comment: Please run SFC /SCANNOW command at administrative Command Prompt and see if that helps.

Comment: @Keith Miller I tried running in safe mode, still the same problem it freezes and takes too much time to open folders

Comment: I ran sfc/scan now again and it says "Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them.
For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at
windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline
repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag."

Comment: @ShubhankarSingh `Dism` should be run prior to `Sfc` _(see [this](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) answer for correct execution)_. If the issue still exists after completing steps 1 - 5, do you have network shares mounted/mapped, else it's likely due to a third party context menu item _(search on here how to check and disable the problematic one)_. Malware/Adware could also cause this, however the aforementioned is more likely.