# Problems with %AppData% folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, appdata

I have two drives in my computer, one SSD and one HDD, but the SSD was getting full so I moved `%AppData%` to the HDD to save space, using a symlink to link them, and navigating to `%AppData%` successfully redirects me. The problems I now have are:

- All taskbar icons are missing shortcuts, which isn't that bad, but the Explorer and Cortana icons don't create a popup when left-clicking them (right-click works correctly)
- File search doesn't work and can't even type into the box (not a problem with the mouse)

I'm not sure what this could be caused by and have tried:

```powershell
# returns no errors
  Sfc /ScanNow

Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

---

*I also had a crash two days ago and something happened to the languages installed, as an uninstalled language was still being used, and I thought I fixed this, but looks to be back*

Comment: IIRC, you cannot move `%AppData%` or `%LocalAppData%` as AFAIK they contain hardlinks. If I'm misremembering, the only other cause would ACLs. _(FYI: `Dism` must be ran before `Sfc` [ [explanation](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) ])_

Answer (score 1):

Try to find more information in the Event Viewer.

But in general, moving the AppData folder to another drive is a cause for
system instability. Not for nothing has Microsoft made it a hidden folder.

I would suggest moving AppData back to its place, hoping that you have not
damaged any sensible folder permissions.
If the instability is not fixed,
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: A repair install will not fix a user profile issue, as the user profiles are not re-created during a repair install [they're merged]; repair installs only deal with `%WinDir%`. The only way to correct a corrupted user profile that is unable to be fixed is to re-create it.

Comment: @JW0914: It might fix some permissions.

Comment: AFAIK, user profiles and the `%UserProfile%` directories are merged and not touched during a repair install as there's no way for a repair install to modify them since they're not contained within the `install.wim`/`install.esd` _(a repair install simply replaces the system files on a PC with those contained within the `install.wim`/`.esd` and doesn't modify ACLs - the ACLs are set at the time of the master ESD/WIM creation and are maintained within the ESD/WIM.)_ The only user profile contained within the `install.esd`/`.esd` is `Default`, the base used to create new user profiles.

Comment: @JW0914: Don't argue too strongly against In-place Upgrade, because it's the last-ditch effort before re-installation from scratch.

Comment: Stating facts isn't arguing... I didn't advocate against repair installs, I simply explained what you're suggesting will not fix the issue you purport it to fix. If disagreeing, please use Microsoft Docs to understand what occurs during an in-place upgrade to the same OS. To merge user profiles into an OS, [USMT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-overview) is required, which is apart of the [ADK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install), not the Windows install ISO or `install.wim`/`install.esd`, intended for use within an LTI/ZTI.