# The computer runs extremely slowly with other strange behavior after adding hard disk

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive

I went to a shop and add a hard disk to my computer. It seems that the computer is extremely slow after that.

Not only the computer is very slow, I got this strange message usually after restart.

[image]

Notice, windows say that this file does not have an app with it performing this action.

What file? What action?

Windows just point to a drive, not to any file with any extension as you can see in that picture.

I am using this computer to type now and I have to wait like 10 seconds before what I type shows up in the screen.

Sometimes another window shows up saying that Microsoft Windows is not responding.

Problems get worse when I try to move 2 TB of data from my external hard disk to the new disk.

Most data move fast except data in one drive folder. I got like 120 GB data in my one drive folder and moving that is extremely slow. I give up and move one drive data back up to another folder. Still very slow.

My plan is to move all data from the external hard drive back up to that folder and then wait for 1 day. Sometimes, the computer is doing fine if I am not moving large amount of data between the 2 hard disks. Well, the last 100GB of data takes a long time to move. It's been a week.

What should I do?

Restarting the computer sometimes help a bit but not my much.

The chance that I get a malware from that new hard disk is extremely small. The technician just install the new hard disk and that's it. I have to activate the hard disk first and format it. Also the technician has no access to my hard disk. Hard disk is protected by bitlocker and only I know the password.

The screen behaves as if the computer runs out of memory or windows handler or some sort of resources

[image]

What should I do?

Update: The problem is greatly reduced now. The computer is very useful. However, typing is still extremely slow.

The symptoms is biggest during and after large files transfer between one hard disk to another (2.3TB of data). Leaving the computer on for a long time (overnight) reduces but does not eliminate the symptom.

Now the computer is very useable.

Currently I suspected that the new drive is the culprit. Howver that's almost impossible. It's not a system drive. Indexing is on that drive. I will change it.

Newest update:

The system is running very well as it should now.

The new hard drive is definitely the culprit but only if combined with one drive. Removing the old drive works.

Unfortunately I discovered this issue after I moved all data to the new drive. So I got to put that d**n drive and move data out to external hard disk again.

Things are fast most of the time at 6-20MB/s. However, when moving files in one drive things are very slow.

Right clicking and left clicking one drive icon in tray does nothing so I just exhaustively wait while playing video games. Turns out after I get back in (after logging in), the effect of my right click shows and I can choose to disable one drive for 24 hours.

After that the computer is just fast. I moved the rest of the file and things are moving fast at 20 mB/s. I can still uses the computer just fine even while the files are moving. No problem whatsoever.

I removed the new drive. It's working fine. All data already moved to external drive.

So next time I have this issue, suspend sync for one drive for 24 hours and then move files.

The new drive is "fine" in every other way. It read and write just fine. It's transfer speed is 20mB/s after one drive stop syncing.

Comment: For the drive, run a short & long S.M.A.R.T test via an Ubuntu install USB, choosing to try Ubuntu, opening a terminal via `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`, issuing: `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install smartmontools; ls /dev | grep sd` _(find the drive, e.g. `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, etc.)_ → If unsure which disk is the new drive: `sudo smartctl -a /dev/<disk>`  → `sudo smartctl -t short; sleep 61; sudo smartctl -a /dev/<disk>; sudo smartctl -t long` _(long test takes several hours; to check progress: `sudo smartctl -a /dev/<disk> | grep progress`)_ → Once test is complete: `sudo smartctl -a /dev/<disk>`

Comment: Was the shop reputable and was the drive brand new?  The app error you're getting can occur from Explorer losing its [file] associations, however that would not occur simply because a new drive was installed. Does disconnecting the drive from the motherboard resolve the issue (shutdown, disconnect drive, reboot)? Unsure why you obfuscated non-pertinent info from screenshot, or is that also an issue; if so, run a system integrity [check](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) and virus/malware scan, as that's not normal under any circumstance.

Comment: I bought the hard disk. The shop only put the hard disk. Also I do not obfuscate anything. The screen does look like that. It looks much better now.

There is no way the shop can install malware even if it wants to. The hard disks are proetected by bitlocker. The exception is the new drive that I formatted first.

Comment: “What should I do?” - Temporarily disconnect the new HDD.  The behavior you describe could be caused by I/O errors.  Windows puts a priority on I/O over user actions, a failing drive, could explain all the behavior including the fact it magically partially went away

Comment: Can I do this through software or also hardware?

Comment: You definitely have OS corruption if system applications have no text... perform a repair install by downloading the Windows install [ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and running `setup.exe` while booted to Windows, choosing to keep all files and settings. Once that's taken care of, troubleshoot the HDD, as it's likely the corruption is part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not the hard disk at all.

The process of changing hard disk seems to trigger a problem in the cpu fan. The cpu fan has dust collecting and that dust block the fan.

I made other questions about this issue and fixing and later replacing the fan works awesome.

[Why does my CPU utilization differ in Hardware Monitor and Task Manager?](https://superuser.com/questions/1618955/why-does-my-cpu-utilization-differ-in-hardware-monitor-and-task-manager)