# Why does my CPU utilization differ in Hardware Monitor and Task Manager?

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage

My computer is extremely slow right now; after running CPUID HW monitor, this is the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Here is another screen shot. I am looking for value of CPU fan to see if it's detected by the software I can't find any.

The CPU fan is death. I removed some dirt and it runs again. That's the main problem all this time.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate at https://superuser.com/questions/1617971/infamous-0-39-ghz-in-windows-10-issue-has-no-fixes along with the top two comments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infamous 0.39 GHz in Windows 10 issue has no fixes?](https://superuser.com/questions/1617971/infamous-0-39-ghz-in-windows-10-issue-has-no-fixes)

Comment: Task Manager does not display the actual utilization (anymore). Instead, it factors in the current CPU frequency scaling state.

Comment: What are your idle temperatures? Your 2nd screenshot shows about 100°C at barely 32% utilization, that still seems to high.

Comment: You are right this is probably a duplicate of that other question. However, the answer to BOTH question is in this question. The other guy twiddle with so many things and doesn't have info from hardware monitor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Your CPU is hot as hell.

The temperature on all cores is over 100°C. It's dropping its frequency as low as it can to prevent damaging itself. HWiNFO says 798 MHz, Task Manager says 0.57 GHz - probably just because they're not sampling simultaneously, but it's not important right now. **You have to fix your CPU cooler immediately, because apparently it's not working at all.** This can lead to permanent CPU and/or motherboard damage.

---

Now, to answer your question, both programs are correct, but they're displaying different information.

HWiNFO is telling you that the CPU is utilized at 100% of the 0.8 GHz clock it's currently running at.

Task Manager says that it's utilized at 17% of its normal 3.4 GHz clock, which is roughly equivalent to 100% utilization at current 0.57 GHz clock.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even see the CPU temperature. Yeah, that definitely looks like a brokern or disconnected cooler causing thermal throttling. Hope OP gets it fixed. Good eyes.

Comment: Is thermal shutoff not implemented on all motherboards when the CPU reaches 100C? Or is that something only certain OEMs do?

Comment: @JW0914 I think it's on the brink of thermal shutoff here. The package is at 104°C and Tjunction for this model is 105°C.

Comment: What tjunction?

Comment: I changed the fan

Comment: @user4951 [Description from Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005597/processors.html)