# Connected to the Internet, but Windows 10 says "No Internet"

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, internet-connection

[image: Internet connectivity]

I'm making this post on a Windows 10 machine, which is certainly connected to the Internet (otherwise I wouldn't be able to make the post in the first place!).

But as the above figure shows, Windows doesn't understand that I'm connected to the Internet. For that reason, it does not download anything from Microsoft Store or Windows Update. (It waits for the Internet connection.)

More info:

1. I'm not using a VPN/Proxy.
2. `ping google.com` works just fine from the command line.
3. I tried `sfc /scannow` and `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`, to no avail.
4. Deleting WiFi driver, or restarting the Windows didn't help.
5. `Network Reset` didn't help.
6. Using other access points wasn't useful either.

I've tried pretty much anything I found on the web, and as a last resort will reinstall Windows. But before that, could you recommend some other solutions?

Comment: What version are you running, as this was a known bug reported months ago?

Comment: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run:   dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup   ,  dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth  , SFC /SCANNOW  . Run these, restart and test.  If these do not work, run a Windows 10 Repair Install before reinstalling Windows.

Comment: @JW0914: It's Version 2004 (Build 19041.685)

Comment: I would google the issue then, as AFAIK, Microsoft patched that bug.  If you didn't run `DISM` prior to `SFC`, those two commands need to be re-run _(see [this](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) answer)_. Does the notification change if you turn WiFi off/on, then reconnect?

Comment: @John I just did that, all over again. The issue persists.

Comment: @JW0914: Followed those instructions, the issue is still there. Turning WiFi off and on doesn't solve it either.

Comment: I have 3 machines here with Wireless - 2 Windows 10 20H2 and 1 21H newer and no issue.  You may have to back up and reinstall Windows 10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer, so I'm posting it for future reference.

Windows uses Active Probing to detect whether internet connectivity is OK ([details](https://networkproguide.com/fix-connect-attempts-to-www-msftconnecttest-com-windows-server-2016/)).

It basically probes some servers using DNS, HTTP, UDP, IPv6, etc. queries to detect the connectivity mode.

[WindowsSpyBlocker](https://github.com/crazy-max/WindowsSpyBlocker) is a tool which checks the issues with this. I ran it, and selected option `1` (Telemetry) and then option `2` (NCSI *= Network Connectivity Status Indicator*):

[image: WindowsSpyBlocker - options 1, then 2]

Choosing option `5` (Test the internet connection) shows the error:

[image: WindowsSpyBlocker - option 5]

It seems that there are IPv6 and UDP problems between my network and Microsoft's default server (`msftconnecttest.com`).

So, I picked option `3` (Apply Firefox NCSI), and then checked again with option `5`. It now works like a charm:

[image: WindowsSpyBlocker - option 5 with Firefox selected as NCSI]

The network indicator is now OK, and Windows Update / Microsoft Store work as expected.

The relevant Registry Key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet`, after applying FireFox NCSI, looks like this:

[image: Registry - after applying FireFox NCSI]

Comment: Nice solution but does not tell us what was wrong with windows and why it shows no internet, I have seen this issue starting with Windows 7. Sometimes disabling your internet adapter, then re-enable it solves it.

Comment: @Moab: The issue is probably my ISP (or some network provider along the way) blocking IPv6 and UDP to the Microsoft-provided default servers.

Comment: Based on your second post, I would say you did a nice job of researching. That is a nice tool, I am going to try it. I have checked it out before but was working on something else at the time. I also have now been having with problems with DNS, etc. always disconnecting on a Windows 7 Home Premium 'Gateway' I brought back to life about a month ago. At least, if it the tool mentioned doesnt help, it can change DNSHost, etc... COOL! and Thnx. Peace

Comment: This worked for me, but either had a ~10min lag after restarting my machine, or required another wifi network restart (which I performed during those 10min)

Answer (score 2):

Based on my understanding, now your issue is that NCSI reports no internet.

The Network Connectivity Status Indicator (NCSI) is a mechanism that controls the internet connectivity display in the Taskbar, among various other functionalities. This mechanism is considered to be a smart notification system for users to know about their current internet status. If the NCSI is unable to perform its function, it will indicate that there is no internet availability, even though the computer is able to access the internet through the browser and ping other IP addresses.

As a workaround, you could try the following methods:

Make sure this registry key `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet]` **EnableActiveProbing** was set to **1**.

Make sure passive probing be enabled as well. In case active probing fails, passive probing can also detect internet unless it’s disabled by GPO. Check below to make sure you didn’t disable passive probing.

Make sure this registry key `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\NetworkConnectivityStatusIndicator]` **NoActiveProbe** was set to **0** (should either not present or value must be 0).

Then please restart the machine and see if NCSI still reports no internet.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you may also need these tools to spoof or bypass NCSI:

- [Jamesits/alwaysonline: Hijack/bypass Windows NCSI and iOS portal detection on a network level.](https://github.com/Jamesits/alwaysonline#which-ip-address-should-i-use)
- [dantmnf/NCSIOverride: You have no Internet connection despite you can open this page. --Microsoft](https://github.com/dantmnf/NCSIOverride)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! There are two things about your answer that could be improved: first of all, please do not post link only answers as the linked site might change, rendering your answer useless. Second: how is this answer better than the accepted one?

Comment: @DarkDiamond You may have underestimated the complexity of this problem, the two links given are extremely professional solutions, there is no better way than to give links.