# Delete Registry key

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, system-restore

I deleted the following Registry key and encountered a lot of problems after restarting the computer:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree\Microsoft\Windows
```

- For example, I cannot type anything in Windows Search, sound does not work correctly, with the worst thing being System Restore doesn't work no matter what I do.

How do I fix this?

Comment: _Rule of thumb: Prior to deleting any Registry key, **always** export the key first (right-click key → Export), which allows you to restore it should any issues arise._ That specific key is massive _(on my PC it's 579KB)_ and is critical to the OS. If a backup of the system hives don't reside in `%WinDir%\System32\config\RegBack`, you'll need to do a repair install as covered in @john's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1627049/529800). You can [try](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) `DISM` & `SFC`, however due to the system hives being fluid, it's not likely they would correct the issue

Comment: "You can try DISM & SFC, however due to the system hives being fluid, it's not likely they would correct the issue"   ...   Very true and that is why I did not suggest  that.

Comment: An FYI in case it helps someone: A few years ago, Windows 10 disabled the auto-creation of the system's Registry hive backups in `%WinDir%\System32\config\RegBack` _(user's hive is stored in `%UserProfile%`)_ and re-enabling the backups via the Registry isn't 100% reliable; however, the program ERUNT can create Registry hive backups and be scheduled to do so at specific intervals. Due to ERUNT's site lacking HTTPS for the download, it's recommended to download it from a trusted third-party, such as [BleepingComputer](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/erunt/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a number of things go wrong from an error as happened here, the best thing to do is a Windows 10 Repair Install. There are 3 ways to proceed:

1. Keep Everything - best if it works and your computer comes back just the way you had set it up except repaired.
2. Keep Data - necessary if the operating system damage is extensive. Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy.
3. Keep Nothing - deletes the User Profile and all else and is essentially a fresh install. Necessary if the User Profile is damage. Be sure you have backed up all your data.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.
>
> Start with the option to Keep Everything.
>
> You can also Keep Data, or Keep Nothing. Keep Nothing is very close to
> a clean install.

Answer (score 1):

If System Restore is enabled, rollback to a save-point from before this registry
update was done.

For more information, see the article
[How to use System Restore on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-system-restore-windows-10).