# Windows 10 bluetooth doesn't work - Enabling not allowed

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

Very often the Windows 10 bluetooth doesn't work properly. In particular, in the notification toolbar I'm not able to enable bluetooth, in the settings I "can" click on enable, but, if I close and then reopen the settings, the button is set on disabled.
[image]

Can you tell me how to overcome this problem please?

Comment: Update the BT drivers. If that doesn't solve it, do steps #1 - 6 in [this](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) answer.

Comment: Hello @JW0914 thank you for your suggestion. After restarting the computer, it works