# Windows stuck in "Preparing Automatic Repair" after an unplanned power-down while disabling WSL

Tags: windows-update, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bootloader, bootrepair

I'm running Windows 10, updated to it's latest version as of writing this on an Acer Predator Helios 300.

Boot times for the laptop have been getting longer, and the system has been slower and laggy in general.  One online forum suggested disabling WSL if not in use. I installed WSL2 long back never used it, so disabling it was worth trying.

I disabled it in Windows Optional Features. This required a reboot after applying the change in Optional Features.  As it was rebooting (during the shutdown process), the laptop battery ran out (0% charge).  As a result, the laptop powered down in the middle of the reboot cycle.

Now Windows starts up with a "Preparing automatic repair" screen, but doesn't progress beyond that point.

Comment: How long does the screen stay on that? Automatic Repair runs programs such as `ChkDsk`, `SFC`, `DISM`, `BootRec`, etc. depending on issue(s) detected _(`ChkDsk` can take hours and`SFC` and `DISM` take ~30min/ea)_. If unplugging USB devices doesn't resolve the issue, boot a Windows install USB [WinPE] → Open terminal via `Shift`+`F10`, then run: `ChkDsk <drive>: /OfflineScanAndFix` for all mounted partitions → `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD` _(if BIOS: `BootRec /FixBoot`)_ → Reboot → If not resolved, boot back to WinPE and perform [steps 1 - 6](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800).

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion, but it turns out the SSD is fully corrupted and I'm forced to get a new one :/

Comment: What do you mean by fully corrupted? That the partition table is gone or that the drive's firmware itself is corrupted, making the drive unusable _(e.g. it's not detected by the BIOS/UEFI firmware - a dirty shutdown will not fry a drive's firmware/PCB and the only way that could occur is via a wiring/grounding issue)_? If the former, [`TestDisk`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) can restore the partition table, as well as recover lost data.

Comment: I tried booting Linux through live usb to run SMART drive check and it gives IO error. Can't read or write to the SSD. Read online that there's no solution and needs to be replaced.

Comment: Unless this is an NVME or mSATA SSD, did you verify the SATA and 12v power harnesses aren't the issue, as well as the SATA port it's plugged into on the motherboard? The drive may very well be fried, however the aforementioned can cause the same error.

Comment: I did remove my HDD(D: and E:) where my files were after running chkdsk on C drive(SSD). But the SSD is the one that is corrupted and where windows is installed. Do you think there might be a correlation? So if it's fried is there any way to salvage it? Like running it somewhere else and formatting?