# How can I restore lost windows store application dll?

Tags: windows, windows-10, dll, windows-store, uwp

I lost windows store application dll by accidentally deleting the it and now I am unable to open the windows store or the emoji panel.

I tried to restore the dlls using `sfc.exe /scannow` and it didn't work out -- I still can't open the emoji panel and the windows store.

When I try to open up a uwp app like the photo app, the app close immediatly after closing.

### Update:

I reinstalled windows through the setting and I still have the problem.

Comment: did you delete it from C:\windows ?  these articles might help: [clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-da2f9573-6eec-00ad-2f8a-a97a1807f3dd) or [missing dll files](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-missing-dll-files-errors-windows),. try running 'WSreset' in a run window

Comment: I get error a message box saying: `ms-windows-store:PurgeCaches File system error(-21472191196)` after a minute or so of running wsreset

Comment: I deleted them from the windows apps folder

Comment: @ViniDalvino Why were you in `%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps`, as there's no reason AFAIK for a user to be in there and is why users have no access to it by default _(you'll want to ensure you remove your user from its ACL)_? `Dism` and `Sfc` may [fix](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) the issue _(they must be run in order specified in Steps 1 - 6)_, but if not, you'll likely need to pull the file from a Windows 10 install USB's  `sources/install.wim` for the version of Win10 you're on _(if it doesn't fix the issue, perform a Repair Install of Windows)_

Comment: I reinstalled windows by resetting window and I still have the problem

Comment: Strictly speaking, Windows Store, doesn’t use a dll since it’s a UWP application.  Since one doesn’t just “delete” Windows Store understanding the exact commands you used to remove it will be helpful in resolving your problem.  You might want to mention what hasn’t worked.  You might also mention what version and edition of Windows 10 you are using.  Might also help to know if your connected to an AD domain or not.  As with all vital information [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP Here, the issue seemed to have fixed itself after several updates.

Answer (score 0):

In an Administrator CMD prompt, run

`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`

[Detailed technical description of the DISM command from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/what-is-dism)

If this doesn't reinstall the Windows Store, you may need to install it from the .appxbundle file. First you can check whether it's already on your machine and can be installed by running the following in an Administrator Powershell session:

```
Get-AppxPackage -allusers Microsoft.WindowsStore | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

If that doesn't work, you'll need to get the .appxbundle file from Microsoft first. The easiest way to get the URL from Microsoft (and not an untrusted third party) is to go to https://store.rg-adguard.net/ and enter this URL which is the link for the Windows store `https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-store/9wzdncrfjbmp`. Change the type from "RP" to "Retail" and it'll generate all the possible Microsoft URLs you may need. Assuming you don't need to reinstall .NET or the Microsoft VC libraries, you can just download the most recent Microsoft.WindowsStore*.appxbundle file. As of today, it's "Microsoft.WindowsStore_11811.1001.2713.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe.appxbundle"

Once you've downloaded that to your local machine, you may be able to double-click it to install it or run `Add-AppxPackage -Path "Microsoft.WindowsStore*.appxbundle"` from an Administrator Powershell in the same directory as you saved the .appxbundle.

Comment: That's only one part of the [equation](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800), as once `/RestoreHealth` runs, `SFC /ScanNow` then needs to be run to replace a system file.

Comment: Is the problem fixed?

Comment: nope. I rested windows and I still can't do nothing. Sorry for the late response