# CPU hitting 100% usage at every new task

Tags: windows-10, laptop, cpu, performance, cpu-usage

So it's been a while since I upgraded my HDD to an SSD, and my disk is no longer the bottleneck. But for the past few weeks my CPU hits 100% if I open any new task. It doesn't matter what I open, I can open chrome, discord, or even something simple as an image and my CPU will hit 100% for a good while. I can also no longer multi-task since using two or more programs literally hangs my laptop for a bit.

Say I open Discord for the first time then discord will take up a good % of CPU in the task manager and my CPU will hit 100%. I can't even play games that I used to be able to play.

Some things I have tried so far:

- Checking out processes in an external program. The problem is independent of any particular process.
- Checked CPU temperatures, they seem to be in control and don't spike on any new task. Max temperature that I get is about 83°C, and normally its about 55-60°C.
- Replaced thermal paste and got my fan oiled.
- Benchmarked my  CPU under a stress test, the findings came back normal.
- Checked my power settings, the CPU runs at max clock speed of 3 GHz.

Oh and in case anybody's wondering I have a ASUS  R558UQ notebook with Intel i5 7200U @2.5GHz running  Windows 10.

Can anyone point out the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: I've seen some Windows 10 devices throttle their CPU speeds down drastically for no reason in the past. Check Task Manager and your Power Options to make sure the CPU is in fact running at the top speed of 2.5 GHz and that there are now power limits in place. Also, what kinds of temperatures are you getting? You should edit your question to include that info.

Comment: Added more info

Comment: I'm assuming you're running at least 8GB of RAM? It's likely third-party application or driver related, but to rule out the OS, perform [Steps 1 - 6](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) and if it doesn't resolve the issue, the most efficient way [time-wise] is likely going to be a Repair Install _(download the Windows install ISO from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), extract the ISO to a partition other than `C:`, then execute `setup.exe` **while booted to Windows**, choosing to keep all files and settings)_

Comment: I had a similar problem on a friend's laptop that I narrowed down to an Intel User Mode Driver related to speed or power management, which I found by drilling down using Process Explorer [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer]. Look for `wudfhost` right-click for properties, and check the threads tab to see if there is a particular named process taking a large chunk of cpu time. If not that one then check for anything else which is using CPU. Google the dlls or processes you suspect might be the culprit and then see if you can toggle it off to test.