# Can't search in the windows search bar, How can I fix it? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, search

**Hello everyone!**

For a few months now I can't use, type or even copy-paste on my windows search bar *(Inside folders, start menu and settings)*.

**I already tried:**

1. Updating windows (10, version 1909).
2. Disabling and Re-enabling Windows search. *(Worked on my Laptop)*
3. De-activating Anti-Virus (Bitdefender).
4. Cleaning Registry and scanning for viruses. *(I do it regularly but still)*

How can I fix this problem and what causes it? *(Both computers had the same issue)*

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to the latest Windows 10 version? A major update may fix such problems.

Comment: _(General FYI: there's no need for the Registry to be "cleaned" - doing so doesn't affect system performance, coming w/ the downside of the cleaner making a mistake and deleting a critical Registry entry, which may/may not be immediately noticeable.)_ Perform [Steps 1 - 6](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) and if it doesn't fix the issue, do a Repair Install, which will also update you to v20H2: [Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) the Windows Setup ISO from Microsoft and launch `setup.exe` **while booted to Windows**, choosing to keep all files