# Windows 7 update to Windows 10 failure - iissetup.exe Exit Code: 340

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, virtualbox, iis, media-creation-tool

I am trying to update a VirtualBox VM running Win7 bit to Win10. I am running the media creation tool in this VM, and it proceeds for a while but eventually fails; I put the log from SetupDiag.exe below:

```
Error: Found AdvancedInstaller Generic failure.
Last Phase: Pre SysPrep 
Last Operation: Upgrade security
Executable: iissetup.exe
Exit Code: 340
Phase: 38
Mode: Install (first install)
Component: Microsoft-Windows-IIS-SharedLibraries-GC, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=x86
Refer to "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes" for error information.

Last Setup Phase:
Phase Name: Pre SysPrep
    Phase Started: 4/27/2021 5:30:31 PM
    Phase Ended: 4/27/2021 5:30:31 PM
    Phase Time Delta: 00:00:00
    Completed Successfully? True


Last Setup Operation:
Operation Name: Upgrade security
    Operation Started: 4/27/2021 5:30:28 PM
    Operation Ended: 4/27/2021 5:30:31 PM
    Operation Time Delta: 0:00:00:03.0000000
    Completed Successfully? True
```

Searching around for information about this, the closest example I could find was [a forum post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/upgrading-from-win-10-1803-to-1903/1cb01cc8-77ac-41e3-90a8-cde65bb51b57?page=2) which basically suggested to remove IIS and retry the update. I've done this (as well as removing any other optional Windows feature that wasn't needed, just because) so now the list of features looks as follows:

[image]

However this did not solve the issue.

A related note was to remove the `\Windows\System32\inetsrv` folder, which I have done; however it was empty (no hidden or system files). But I have yet to retry the install again after that because it takes so much time and I thought I should ask here before proceeding.

---

Note - prior to attempting the update I followed [instructions here](https://tunecomp.net/upgrade-windows-7-8-1-to-windows-10-on-virtualbox-virtual-machine/) to modify the VM settings. I don't know if running in the VM has anything to do with this problem (it doesn't seem like it) but thought this was worth mentioning.

Comment: You cannot upgrade a 32-bit version of Windows to a 64-bit version of Windows.  You would have to reinstall Windows, and the setup cannot be started from within Windows, for obvious reasons

Comment: @Ramhound that's a great point (though not necessarily the cause of this issue?) I thought when I downloaded the media creation tool it was the 64 bit version, but maybe not - or maybe it just will do whatever it thinks is "right"?

Comment: It’s not; Your upgrade to Windows 10 32-bit is simply failing.  Boot to the ISO and install Windows 10 64-but, and yes, that means the previous installation gets wiped but there isn’t another upgrade path.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you... though a 32 bit update may still have some value. I'm going to edit the question accordingly.

Comment: The error you received based on my research is basically indicating Windows is blocking the upgrade due to a compatibly issue with a device.  The callout of iissetup.exe is probably a red haring.  The one tool that could help diagnose the issue only supports Windows 10

Comment: @Ramhound if that's true then it does sound more likely to be a virtual machine compatibility issue, maybe? Since any of the devices are of course just virtualized or pseudo.

Comment: @StayOnTarget Backup the VM by capturing a [WIM](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) and perform [Steps 3 -6](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800), however there's no guarantee that will fix the issue and you may end up having to clean install anyway _(why I recommend capturing a WIM of the VM)_. There's no purpose in maintaining a 32bit Windows environment since there's no benefit or reason to, while at the same time imposing substantial performance hindrances, such as a max of 4GB of RAM. _(Don't manually modify `%WinDir%`, as `SFC` will almost always undo such modifications.)_

Comment: @JW0914 unfortunately the main reason for prolonging this particular 32bit VM is that the effort to reinstall a bunch of things on it is quite large. Otherwise it would have been done away with a long time ago. I'll check out your links, thank you

Comment: @StayOnTarget There are deployment tools within the ADK (AIK for Win7) that can help with migration, such as USMT _(I know user profiles can be migrated without issue, but am unsure about programs installed outside of `%LocalAppData%` and `%AppData%` as I used MDT prior to Win10 to do so)_. Normally `DISM` [specifically `/StartComponentCleanup` and `/RestoreHealth`] would be used to resolve Component Store issues _(which is what your issue is)_, but it didn't have that support until Windows 8, so the SUR tool must be utilized in Win7 to do so.