# Windows 10 Update Failure (2021-05 Version 20H2) KB5003173

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, dism

I am updating my Windows 10 PC to v20H2 and it's stuck at 20%, stating it cannot be installed due to error `0x800f0831`:

- CBS Log:

  ```
  Info    CBS   Store corruption, manifest missing for package: Windows-Defender-ApplicationGuard-Inbox-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.19041.789
  Error   CBS   Failed to resolve package 'Windows-Defender-ApplicationGuard-Inbox-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.19041.789' [HRESULT = 0x800f0831 - CBS_E_STORE_CORRUPTION]
  Info    CBS   Mark store corruption flag because of package: Windows-Defender-ApplicationGuard-Inbox-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.19041.789. [HRESULT = 0x800f0831 - CBS_E_STORE_CORRUPTION]
  Info    CBS   Failed to resolve package: Windows-Defender-ApplicationGuard-Inbox-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.19041.789 [HRESULT = 0x800f0831 - CBS_E_STORE_CORRUPTION]
  Info    CBS   Plan: Start to process package watchlist.
  Info    CBS   Package Format: PSFX
  Info    CBS   Store corruption, manifest missing for package: Package_for_DotNetRollup~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.4330.6
  Error   CBS   Failed to resolve package 'Package_for_DotNetRollup~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.4330.6' [HRESULT = 0x800f0831 - CBS_E_STORE_CORRUPTION]
  Info    CBS   Mark store corruption flag because of package: Package_for_DotNetRollup~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.4330.6. [HRESULT = 0x800f0831 - CBS_E_STORE_CORRUPTION]
  Info    CBS   Failed to resolve package [HRESULT = 0x800f0831 - CBS_E_STORE_CORRUPTION]
  Info    CBS   Failed to check whether this is the real child: Package_for_DotNetRollup~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.4330.6 [HRESULT = 0x800f0831 - CBS_E_STORE_CORRUPTION]
  Info    CBS   Failed to collect affected dependent package for package: Microsoft-Windows-CoreEdition~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.19041.844 [HRESULT = 0x800f0831 - CBS_E_STORE_CORRUPTION]
  Info    CBS   Failed to process package watchlist. [HRESULT = 0x800f0831 - CBS_E_STORE_CORRUPTION]
  Info    CBS   Failed to plan execution. [HRESULT = 0x800f0831 - CBS_E_STORE_CORRUPTION]
  Error   CBS   Failed to process single phase execution. [HRESULT = 0x800f0831 - CBS_E_STORE_CORRUPTION]
  Info    CBS   WER: Generating failure report for package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~19041.985.1.6, status: 0x800f0831, failure source: CBS Other, start state: Absent, target state: Installed, client id: UpdateAgentLCU
  Info    CBS   Not able to query DisableWerReporting flag.  Assuming not set... [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
  ```
- I have run the following:

  ```bsh
  Sfc /ScanNow
    # Returns back nothing needs to be repaired

  ChkDsk /Scan
    # Nothing to be repaired

  Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

    Error:
    Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
    Version: 10.0.19041.844

    Image Version: 10.0.19042.844

    [==========================100.0%==========================]
    Error: 0x800f081f

    The source files could not be found.
    Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature.
    For more information on specifying a source location, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

    The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
  ```

How do I troubleshoot this, as I have surfed the internet and no resources are found that can be used in this case?

Comment: Look at the following post:  [Error 0x800f0831 when you install an update](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/mem/configmgr/error-0x800f0831-installing-update). _This article fixes an issue in which you receive error 0x800f0831 when you install a cumulative update_. If you are working in the company environment (example, under Active Directory control) perhaps the server configured to block some external resource. Try the resolution described in this post. Perhaps the help of the system administrator is required.

Comment: You need to update your .NET installation

Comment: It's complaining that windows defender isn't installed. I would try reinstalling windows defender and then try the upgrade.

Comment: You ran `Sfc` and `Dism` in the wrong order - please perform [Steps 1- 6](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) and the problem should resolve

Comment: @MarkScheck - One does not “reinstall” Windows Defender on Windows 10

Comment: @Ramhound seems like lots of people have this issue.https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_defender-protect_start-windows_10/how-do-i-reinstall-windows-defender-for-windows-10/76c37289-9896-4592-a302-1e819627ad9c?page=3

Comment: @Ricardolcm - It appears you will have to use [DISM /RestoreHealth /Source:wim](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) syntax instead of the command you used.  You probably will have to be explicate about which index to use, so you will have to determine what the index for the edition is, for whatever Windows image you use.

Comment: @MarkScheck - Lot's of people having a problem does not change the fact, you cannot reinstall Windows Defender, it's part of your installation and would require you to reinstall Windows in order to repair any damage to that particular component.  **The thread you linked to was from 2016 by the way and thus has nothing to do with the author's problem.**

Comment: @Ricardolcm - I will submit an answer tonight, that should resolve the problem, otherwise it will at least provide more diagnostic information.

Comment: @Ricardolcm - Can you please provide the appropriate amount of information from `C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log`, hopefully, limited to only the error contained within it.

Comment: @Tekkie_Boy Where can I find the pakcage?

Comment: @Ramhound DISM log: https://pastebin.com/GbMA5z7G

Comment: @Ricardolcm - The solution will be to perform an in-place repair

Comment: @Ramhound Can you make it as a solution since it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out the solution with the help from Ramhound.

If you are facing such situations, try to do a in-place repair.

The following website will help

- https://www.wintips.org/repair-windows-10-with-in-place-upgrade/

Answer (score 0):

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/uanble-to-install-windows-updates-error-code/ef2cc766-2243-4e50-94d8-ce7d16538242

try running the 'DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth' as adm before the restore, seemed to work for me

Comment: I tried, and still the above error happened, you may see the DISM log in https://pastebin.com/GbMA5z7G

Answer (score -2):

If you had uninstalled Edge Chromium from your Windows10, then please re-install it and try again windows update, it will work.

---

Windows 10 20H2-05 (KB5003173) | Error Code (0x800f0922) | Unable to complete updates. Undoing changes