# Can't open Device Manager in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, device-manager

If I try to open Device Manager, an error message will pop up:

```
MMC cannot open the file C:\WINDOWS\system32\devmgmt.msc
```

I have already searched for solutions, but there was nothing that seemed like my problem. How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: If access permissions are not the issue, perform [Steps 1 - 6](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800)

Comment: `Dism` and `Sfc` are executed from an Admin terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try the first and simplest repair: DISM and SFC .

> Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> SFC /SCANNOW
>
> Restart when all the above is complete and test.

====

Then, if the initial repair did not work, use the Windows 10 Repair Install.

> Go to the Media Creation Link:
>
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
>
> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally. Use the option to
> Keep Everything.

Comment: Hello John

Thank you for your answer. I just have a few questions. How to open the DISM.exe. And after opening the DISM.exe. How do I enter ```Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup.```And ```DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth```

Comment: I have yet to see this generic solution (DISM and SFC) solve anything ever.  I think this might be the one case where it actually does something of use.  Please let me know if this solution (posted over and over) was of any help.

Comment: At the administrative command prompt, enter the complete dism string as I posted.  I think component cleanup might likely replace (fix) devmgmnt

Comment: Is it normal if you type in after the `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup` that it says `The system cannot find the path specified`?

Comment: If you do all 3 steps (2 DISM, 1 SFC) and restart and still cannot find the Device Manager file, then proceed with the Windows 10 Repair Install outlined.

Comment: Hello John

I just did all 3 steps. And it worked! Now I can open the Device Manager. I want to thank you so much for helping! Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks for the update and I am glad the 3 step process worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to John's answer.

1. Start > Run > `MMC`
2. File > Add/Remove Snap-in (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>)
3. Select `Device Manager` from the list, and click `Add >`
4. Click OK to close the dialog

[image]