# Black screens with artifacts when installing software in W10

Tags: windows-10

Often when installing new software or unzipping on Windows 10 [b. 19043], I'm getting black flashes and portions of the screen go black (screenshots below):

- **Motherboard:** Asus ROG STRIX B550-F GAMING
- **CPU:** AMD Ryzen 5 5600X
- **GPU:** Asus Radeon RX 6700 XT 12GB ROG STRIX GAMING OC
- **RAM:** (2x) Kingston HyperX Fury 16 GB DDR4-3200 CL16
- **SSD:** Kingston A2000 500GB M.2-2280 NVME
- **PSU:** System Power 9 600 W 80+ Bronze Certified ATX

I've tried an antivirus scan, reinstalling graphics drivers, `sfc /scannow`, `chkdsk`, Windows Memory Diagnostic, killing and restarting `explorer.exe`, and changing the resolution.

Any suggestions on what to do please?

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]
[image: Screenshot3]

Comment: Info about your hardware will help, for computer and display adapter.

Comment: @harrymc added the computer spec to the question

Comment: Which `explorer.exe` are you killing, File Explorer [Background processes] or the Windows Shell [Windows processes]? Instead of killing `explorer.exe`, does ending the task of `Desktop Windows Manager` [Windows processes] have any effect? At first glance, it appears GPU driver-related or a context shell-like issue that's causing DWM [Desktop Windows Manager] to hang/crash _(you could try [Steps 1 - 6](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) to double-check it's not system file corruption, but that doesn't seem likely)_. Event Viewer might be useful, but I'm unsure what logs should be checked.

Comment: The GPU has a pretty recent [driver](https://rog.asus.com/graphics-cards/graphics-cards/rog-strix/rog-strix-rx6700xt-o12g-gaming-model/helpdesk_download). Are you using it?

Comment: Does this perhaps happen with all UAC prompts?

Comment: @harrymc yes, the latest beta driver from amd

Comment: My driver is from ASUS.

Comment: @daniel, I'm not sure what do you mean?

Comment: @harrymc I think it's the same driver, it's AMD Adrenaline,

Comment: What is left is to [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html), to set all Windows components to a known state. This is the same as doing a major Windows update.

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for the suggestion, when I end the task of Desktop Windows Manager everything goes back to normal. Any idea of what the next step in preventing this from happening could be?

Comment: @Blücher I'm unsure on how to troubleshoot this in an efficient manner that's not time-consuming. harrymc's suggestion of a Repair Install is where I'd start, and if it continues afterward, it's likely either driver or a context shell-like issue _(for the former, there may be event log entries in Event Viewer, but I'm unsure of which one to look within; for the latter, Nirsoft and SysInternals both have tools to troubleshoot content shell-like issues by disabling half, seeing if the issue is fixed, disabling other half and if the issue resolves, continue whittling it down by half)_