# Run sfc /scannow or chkdsk /f first

Tags: hard-drive, chkdsk, sfc

Is it better to run `ChkDsk /f` first, then `Sfc /ScanNow` or is it better to run the other way around, and does it matter which is run first, as I see no guides online saying which is the best option?

Comment: If filesystem corruption is suspected, `ChkDsk` would likely be the first one would want to run first to ensure a corrupted filesystem doesn't create an issue for `Sfc` and `Dism`, which [must](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) be run before `Sfc`

Answer (score 1):

The two commands are very different and for different purposes and, from this perspective, it does not matter which one you run first:

- `CHKDSK` is a command to check the file system and files on your disk. It can tell you about the drive health of your disk and filesystem.
- `SFC` [System File Checker] is a tool to correct Windows software in your OS by using a secured Windows Storage folder to get corrected versions for system files.

I would only use CHKDSK if I suspected disk errors; my vendor hardware diagnostics tell me my drives are fine, so I do not `CHKSDSK`.

I run `SFC`, preceded by `DISM`, on Windows 10 if I experience strange things or errors, as `DISM` and `SFC` have some ability to correct such errors.

Comment: For those that don’t know what DISM is: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/what-is-dism

Comment: Filesystem errors aren't only caused by hardware errors. Hardware self-diagnostics turning green don't tell you anything about the condition of filesystem.

Comment: What was the reason for the downvote 2 years later?

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2yr old 4tb Seagate ext. HD. Over a month ago, something happened to where the drive was non-responsive, yet showing on my pc. I tried a number of suggestion. Nothing worked.
When I came across an article about the Scannow process. I did it, the scan took 5minutes and it actually found and fixed some of my issues.

Go the Scannow process, it worked for me. When its done, disconnect hd, reboot and reinsert.

Comment: Does not answer question.