# Laptop always turns itself on again

Tags: windows-10, laptop, power-supply, hardware-failure, acpi

Since yesterday my Laptop won't turn off anymore. When I shut it down, it takes a few seconds and then it turns itself on again. Doesn't matter if I let it boot and shutdown again, or turn it of in pre-boot.

I've disconnected all external devices. It happens on power supply as well as battery power. Had to remove both to keep it off.

When I plugged it back in this morning, it stayed off. I then booted it and directly shut it down again for a test and got the same behaviour.

Laptop is a HP ProBook 650 G1 with Windows 10.

Any ideas was this could be? I'm thinking hardware failure right now but I'm at a loss. I don't even know how to tag this question :-)

**EDIT**

Things I tried according to comments:

- `powercg /LASTWAKE` -> zero entries
- Disabled automatic restart after failure
- Checked Fast Boot option, was already disabled
- Wake Timers disabled
- No matching task schedules

I also experimented a little more. These are the test cases:

- Shutdown Windows normally -> happens
- Interrupt startup before boot after normal shutdown -> happens
- Interrupt after normal shutdown and leave without power over night -> doesn't happen
- Switch off booted machine hard (long press power button) -> doesn't happen
- Interrupt startup before boot after hard off -> doesn't happen

**EDIT 2**

`powercfg -energy` resulted in 6 errors. Unfortunatley the report is in my system language German, I'll try to translate/summarize

- 4 errors about energy policy (disabled automatic standby, screen off/darkening)
- High CPU load
- PCI Express-ASPM (Active-State Power Management) disabled due to known hardware incompatability

Comment: Windows has planned task and other options for waking a PC. Check the command-line command `powercfg /LASTWAKE` if it displays something reasonable why your computer woke up.

Comment: @Robert thanks for the hint but it has zero entries

Comment: @NetServOps it's a HP ProBook 650 like written in the question. I always keep Windows up to date but no installs yesterday.

Comment: @AndréStannek HP ProBook 650 but is it G8 or older? I would advise to update the BIOS if not already

Comment: @NetServOps I see now that I was a little unprecise. It's even a G1. BIOS is up to date.

Comment: @AndréStannek Perhaps during shutdown, there is some kind of system software failure which is causing the system to enter into restart.
The OS has a configuration for this, check to see if its ticked to restart automatically on system failure, and if it is ticked then untick and try shutdown again and see what happens.
To check, in search box type 'advanced system settings', then choose the 'Startup and Recovery' settings button, then you can see in there if 'Automatically restart' is ticked under 'System failure'

Comment: @NetServOps it was enabled so I changed it but sadly it didn't solve it.

Comment: @AndréStannek But when you try to shutdown, did you see anything flash up or anything at all to indicate an issue? And just to clarify, when you try to shutdown, does it actually turn all the way off and then goes back through the BIOS startup again or you don't see bios?

Comment: @AndréStannek Also, try disabling fast boot - "Power Options > Change what the power buttons do > Change settings that are currently unavailable > Disable Turn on fast start-up"

Comment: @NetServOps you gave me another idea. I've just tested a forced power off. See my edits.

Comment: @AndréStannek Ok perhaps try one other thing, run a power report. Open CMD as admin, and run command: PROMPT> powercfg -energy -output C:\Temp\PowerReport.html - then when it finishes after 60 seconds, open the report from the saved location and see what power problems it flags, if any.

Comment: @NetServOps see edit again

Comment: @AndréStannek Ok after checking these things, I am thinking it is a hardware issue. The laptop is quite old so it is not something which should be surprising. Time to upgrade your laptop perhaps? One last thing to try is 'reset this pc'. Type that in search and do that. Then see if problem still persists after this.

Comment: @NetServOps I'd really like to avoid a reset. It's a company laptop anyways, so time for an upgrade I guess. Thanks for all your help :-)

Comment: @AndréStannek Did you try to [disable wake timers](https://softwaretested.com/windows/computer-turns-on-by-itself-after-shutdown-what-to-do/#Fix_3_Change_Advanced_Power_Settings_and_Disable_the_Allow_Wake_Timers_Option)?

Comment: Does the OS actually shutdown _(if shutting down and rebooting, you'd see POST  → BIOS/UEFI → Windows Bootloader → Login screen)_? If it's not shutting down, power settings/`powercfg` don't track, as while they interact with the shutdown process, they don't control it and wouldn't result in an inability to shut down the OS; this would either be an OS _([Steps 1 - 6](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800))_ or a hardware _(run BIOS/UEFI hardware diagnostics long test)_ issue. If it is shutting down and rebooting, check Task Scheduler and wake timers, as well as the BIOS/UEFI firmware settings.

Comment: @Lluser it's already disabled

Comment: @JW0914 yes, it acctually shuts down

Comment: Does the problem occur if you have it plugged in with the AC adapter but *also* have the battery removed?

Comment: Btw, I learned something here while searching around for similar issues: HP support *sucks*, haha. Those HP support forums are full of support staff just straight up ghosting people in the middle of a conversation.

Comment: @JasonC yes, tried all three combinations of battery and power supply.