# Do I have to initialize my new SSD before performing backup and partition?

Tags: windows, partitioning, ssd, system-restore, nvme

I bought a new NVME SSD to use as my primary/boot drive. My old SSD is going to still be in my PC and be used as extra storage.

I installed the NVME SSD into my PC. It doesn't show up in my file explorer, but it does show up on disk manager.

It says that the drive is not initialized and it asks me if I want to initialize it with MBR or GPT. I'm not sure what to do for this.

I want to use AOMEI Backupper to move everything from my old SSD to my new one, but I don't know if I need to initialize the new SSD first and whether to use MBR or GPT.

Keep in mind that my new SSD does not yet have Windows on it, as I am planning to transfer Windows from my old SSD to my new one using AOMEI Backupper

Comment: I'm reading _"I want to use AOMEI Backupper to move everything from my old SSD to my new one"_ as an intention to clone the old drive. In that case initializing the new one shouldn't be necessary, but it also wouldn't do any harm.

Comment: “I bought a new NVME SSD to use as my primary/boot drive. It says that the drive is not initialized and it asks me if I want to initialize it with MBR or GPT.” - Neither; Boot to the AOMEI environment while in UEFI mode and duplicate your existing disk.  This will automatically use GPT.

Answer (score 6):

> I installed the NVME SSD into my PC. It doesn't show up in my file
> explorer, but it does show up on disk manager.
>
> It says that the drive is not initialized and it asks me if I want to
> initialize it with MBR or GPT. I'm not sure what to do for this.
>
> I want to use AOMEI Backupper to move everything from my old SSD to my
> new one, but I don't know if I need to initialize the new SSD first
> and whether to use MBR or GPT.

You need to initialize the SSD in Disk Management in order to see it in File Explorer and to install  new system.

However, You may not need to initialize the disk just to use AOMEI Backupper.

I put a screen shot below showing how to initialize your disk if you wish to do so. There is no harm done initializing a disk.

New disks are normally GPT and you should format it that way. This disk is for your primary boot disk and so should be formatted as GPT. This drive is for Windows 10 and using GPT is the best way to go.

**Also, you said "I want to use AOMEI Backupper to move everything from my old SSD to my new one":**  While it is not always necessary, I always suggest doing a fresh install to prevent errors (from the existing system used for some months / years) from creeping in. This has always worked better for me and will pay handsome dividends in the future.  This is the same computer so Windows will activate properly.

.
.

Use Disk Management to Initialize:

[image]

Comment: MBR partition is limited to 2 Terabytes, if more GPT is necessary.

Comment: Why would a clean install be necessary, as that's _entirely unnecessary_ - Capture a WIM of the existing OS partition and apply it to the new one, which I cover [here](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800)

Comment: @John How exactly will errors "creep in" when capturing an image of the existing OS partition and applying it to the new OS partition via `Dism`? _(Please fact check your info, as this is how all OEMs provision new PCs/laptops, and how businesses deploy their PCs, coupled with the multitude of man page links for reference in the link I previously provided.)_

Comment: For a new installation, which you suggested, you don't need to initialize the SSD at all. Just use Windows Media Creator to download a Windows installation image, put it on a 8GB+ USB pen drive, boot from it and install it to the empty SSD. Done.

Comment: “I strongly suggest doing a fresh install to prevent the inevitable old errors from creeping in.” - Nonsense. I have copied and transferred the same installation to multiple computers for more than a decade without any issues.

Comment: It is not "nonsense" Look at all the issues in here with existing systems that need major repairs to correct and even fresh installs to correct. I am not saying your post is incorrect, merely that look around and there are many many OS errors in here not easily corrected.

Comment: @John I understand the point you're making to a point, however a clean install, versus capturing/applying a WIM and doing a repair install, is simply inefficient & inconvenient for the user, as it requires reinstalling all programs, reconfiguring any tweaks made to programs and the OS, etc. There are literally only a couple of OS issues that cannot be [fixed](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) via `Dism` & `Sfc`, with the main one being Registry modifications; any other issues would likely be 3rd party related or a corrupted User Profile _(only fix is to create a new User Profile)_

Answer (score 3):

> *I want to use AOMEI Backupper to move everything from my old SSD to my new one, but I don't know if I need to initialize the new SSD first and whether to use MBR or GPT.*

- All drives must be initialized with a partition table prior to use and if you have a UEFI motherboard, GPT is recommended
- Windows natively supports capturing/applying partition images 
   *(using 3rd party solutions often results in issues, which I cover near the end of [this](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) answer)*

---

*(Regardless of section, `O:` refers to the *applicable* old partition, `N:` to the *applicable* new partition)*

1. **Configure the required partitions on the new drive:** <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → *Open:* [`DiskPart`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart) → *OK*

   1. **Select the new drive and create the partition table:**

      ```bash
      Lis Dis
      Sel Dis #
      Clean
      ```

      **UEFI:**

      ```bash
      Convert Gpt
      ```
   2. **Create boot partition:**

      - **[BIOS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-biosmbr-based-hard-drive-partitions#system-partition):**

        ```bash
        Cre Par Pri offset=1024 Size=100
        Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=Boot
        Active
        ```
      - **[UEFI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/hard-drives-and-partitions#system-and-utility-partitions):**

        ```bash
        Cre Par EFI Size=100
        Format Quick Fs=FAT32 Label=EFI
        Assign Letter=Y
        Cre Par Msr Size=16
        ```
   3. **Create OS partition, with:**

      - **Rest of the drive as the OS partition:**

        - **[BIOS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-biosmbr-based-hard-drive-partitions#windows-partition):**

          ```bash
          Cre Par Pri
          Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=System
          Shrink desired=1024 min=1024
          ```
        - **[UEFI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#windows-partition):**

          ```bash
          Cre Par Pri Id=ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
          Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=System
          Shrink desired=1024 min=1024
          ```

      ***- or -***

      - **Additional partitions after the [300GB] OS partition:** <sup>*(multiply size by 1024: `300*1024=307200`)*</sup> 
         <sup>*Max size required is ~300GB if not storing User Data directories on `C:` (recommended)*</sup>

        - **BIOS:**

          ```bash
          Cre Par Pri Size=307200
          Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=System
          Shrink desired=1024 min=1024
          ```
        - **UEFI:**

          ```bash
          Cre Par Pri Size=307200 Id=ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
          Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=System
          Shrink desired=1024 min=1024
          ```
   4. **Create WinRE partition:** 
       <sup>*Must have 320MB free; `WinRE.wim` is ~420MB in size (allow for future size increases)*</sup>

      - **[BIOS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-biosmbr-based-hard-drive-partitions#recovery-tools-partition):**

        ```bash
        Cre Par Pri Size=768 Id=27
        Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=WinRE
        Exit
        ```
      - **[UEFI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#recovery-tools-partition):**

        ```bash
        Cre Par Pri Size=768 Id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
        Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=WinRE
        Gpt Attributes=0x8000000000000001
        Exit
        ```
2. **Boot to [WinRE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference):** *Settings* → *Update & Security* → *Recovery* → *Advanced startup*: *Restart now* →  
     *Advanced* → *Troubleshooting* → *Command Prompt*

   1. **Determine drive letters of the old and new OS partitions:**

      ```bash
      DiskPart
        Lis Vol
        Exit
      ```
   2. **[Capture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#capture-image) WIM of the old OS partition:** 
       <sup>*(Save to a partition containing free space of ~40% the size of the data on the OS partition)*</sup>

      ```bash
      Dism /Capture-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /CaptureDir:"O:" /Name:"Windows Backup" /Description:"Base Image 2022.01.09 @ 18:40" /Compress:Max /CheckIntegrity /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:"
      ```
   3. **[Apply](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#apply-image) WIM to the new OS partition:**

      ```bash
      Dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /Index:1 /ApplyDir:"N:" /CheckIntegrity /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:"
      ```
   4. **Create [boot files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di) on the new drive:** 
       <sup>*(Don't add the old OS when asked in the last [`BootRec`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/advanced-troubleshooting-boot-problems#method-2-repair-boot-codes) command)*</sup>

      - **BIOS:**

        ```bash
        BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD
        ```
      - **UEFI:**

        ```bash
        ::# Mount EFI partition:
            DiskPart → Lis Vol → Sel Vol # → Assign Letter=Y → Exit

        ::# Create EFI directories and enter:
            MkDir "Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot"
            Cd /d "Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot"

        ::# Create EFI boot structure:
            BootRec /Fixboot

            ::# If Access Denied error occurs:
                BcdBoot N:\Windows /s N: /f UEFI

        ::# Resolve any other boot issues:
            BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD

        ::# Unmount EFI partition:
            DiskPart → Sel Vol Y → Remove → Exit
        ```
3. **Copy `WinRE.wim` from old drive's WinRE partition to the new one:**

   ```bash
   # Refer to drive letters from #2.1: (if unsure: Sel Vol # → Det Par)
     RoboCopy /E /Sec "O:\Recovery" "N:\Recovery"
   ```
4. **Reboot:** [`wpeutil reboot`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/wpeutil-command-line-options) → **Configure WinRE once booted back to Windows:**

   1. **Open an Admin Terminal:** **<kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>** → *Open*: `powershell` → **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>**+*OK*
   2. **Mount new drive's WinRE partition:**

      ```bash
      DiskPart
        Lis Vol
        Sel Vol #
        Assign Letter=Z
        Exit
      ```
   3. **Configure WinRE:**

      ```bash
      # Disable WinRE:
        ReAgentC /Disable

      # Set Custom WinRE Path:
        ReAgentC /SetREimage /Path "Z:\Recovery\WindowsRE"

      # Enable WinRE and verify:
        ReAgentC /Enable ; ReAgentC /Info
      ```
   4. **Remove WinRE mount point:** `DiskPart` → `sel vol z` → `remove` → `exit`

Comment: Wow, great answer! DISM is very powerful, yes, but it's only suitable for power users who are quite firm on the command line (terminal or shell). **OT:** The German computer magazine c’t (stands for *computer and technology*) created a script called c’t-WIMage. It semi-automates the tedious task of regular Windows backups, and puts them incrementally on an external + bootable disk. With it one can boot into Windows RE and restore any backed-up state quite easily. Find c’t-WIMage at this link: https://heise.de/-3863074 (in German, sorry).

Comment: @luttztfz Command-line isn't just for power users and I wish folks would stop propagating that perception because if a user can type, they are intelligent enough to use the command line, as the only difference between a GUI and command-line program is typing; it could be argued command-line programs are actually easier to use since the man page parameters of the command are easily accessible via `/?` or `help`/`-help`. At first glance, c't-WIMage looks awesome and the only thing I don't like about it is the lack of compression by default since the WIM becomes a base backup image for the system

Comment: **If downvoting an answer, please leave a comment explaining why** _(I'm baffled why this was down-voted since it's literally word for word from Microsoft Docs and contains the requisite man page links - there is nothing in this answer that's subjective or factually inaccurate)_

Comment: You're probably right about the command-line... Me personally, I love the Unix shell but I have a hard time adapting to the PowerShell, which I don't use very often, so that's probably why. I have to correct my statement though: very complicated tasks, with lots of steps and details to think about, become quite tedious and sometimes a very simple mistake, like a typo, or a logical error, can interfere with its success. Using an automated program to do drive cloning can sometimes be as easy as "from here to there", which is my recommendation regardless of GUI or CLI...

Answer (score 2):

“Initialize” means to format and/or partition the storage media.

I assume you are using Windows from another internal installation and want to *move* or *clone* it to the newly installed SSD. Some SSD manufacturers have special editions of “migration software”, which will do the moving job for you, hence you don't need to initialize the new SSD. For example, Western Digital (SanDisk) provides a free special edition of Acronis True Image in their [downloads section](https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx), which will only work with WD/SanDisk drives. Other SSD manufacturers have similar software.

The software is often guided and will clone your current installation, including shrinking it if necessary, to the new SSD. There is no initialization of the SSD needed beforehand.

You really need to do **drive cloning**, since copying only the Windows partition will have you loose the boot information on the new SSD. As a result, Windows will not be able to boot from the NVMe SSD. With *AOMEI Backupper* the free edition [should have](https://www.ubackup.com/clone/ssd-cloning-freeware-4348.html) the clone function...

So your **STEP 1** is the cloning operation. Be sure to get this one right, and when it's done, you should have a `C:\Windows` and something like a `D:\Windows` (could also be another letter, but you should be able to identify it as the newly cloned drive).

To make the later steps easier, mark the original and the clone after the cloning is complete, by simply creating a new text file from Windows Explorer: one file on `C:\`, which you could name `OLD-Windows.txt`, and on the cloned Windows partition e.g. `D:\NEW-Windows.txt`. (No text needed, just the filename to identify the partition later. So the files will have a file size of 0.)

On to **STEP 2**...

Once the cloning is done, I recommend to run `bcdedit` from the elevated Windows Command Prompt. But first you need to mount the ESP, short for “EFI System Partition”, on the cloned drive. This is important, since you will want to select the NVMe-SSD as your primary boot device once you've moved (cloned) Windows.

To do that, first execute an elevated command prompt. Use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and select “Command Prompt (Admin)” (Windows 8/10) or “Windows Terminal (Admin)” (Windows 11), although [there is more than one way](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-an-elevated-command-prompt-2618088) to do this.

Then type `diskpart` <kbd>↩ Enter</kbd> and find the ESP [like so](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/cant-access-efi-system-partition) (likewise always followed by <kbd>↩</kbd>):

- `list disk`
- `select disk` **`n`**
- `list partition`
- `select partition` **`n`**
- `assign letter=`**`z`**
- `exit`

Replace the **n** by the disk representing the SSD (e.g. `select disk 1`) and again (a different *n* that is) by the partition of the ESP. You can also try the command `list volume` (and `select volume` **`n`**), but I don't think it should be necessary.

Be careful, since you now have two similar drives, the original one and the cloned one! Be logical about it: If `C:` is on the old (currently booted) partition, then the newly cloned SSD will have the Windows partition with another drive letter, maybe `D:`. So if you see `C:` on the disk you selected, select the other one. Be also logical about the ESP: It contains the EFI boot loaders and boot configuration for Windows, and by default Microsoft makes it a 200 MB FAT32 partition. It's label is probably “System” or “ESP” or similar. It will be present on both drives after the cloning process! (If it is on the same drive as `C:` is, choose the other one!)

Once you've identified and selected the ESP on the cloned drive, assign a drive letter to it, in the above example **Z:** (but you may freely choose any available drive letter of your liking), and exit Diskpart.

Now we simply [use BCDEdit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di?view=windows-11) to add a new boot configuration, as follows (explaining each option separately):

- `bcdboot`
- `D:\Windows` – replace `D:` with the drive letter of the cloned Windows partition
- `/l en-us` – language selection (optional); change to your liking (e.g. `ja-jp`)
- `/s Z:` – replace `Z:` by the drive letter of the EFI System Partition (ESP)
- `/v` – verbose mode (for better failure analysis, in case of an error)
- `/p` – select the cloned Windows partition as the default EFI boot option
- `/c` – don't preserve the previous boot configuration (which was cloned and most likely wrong anyway)

The full command looks like this: `bcdboot D:\Windows /l en-us /s Z: /v /p /c`

With this command the ESP on the cloned drive should be updated for the newly cloned Windows partition **and** the UEFI boot selection from the computer should also default to the newly installed drive. Thus, when you now reboot your system, which you should do, it will be booted from the cloned drive. But since it's a clone, it will look exactly the same, only `C:` is now on the NVMe-SSD. You will see a `D:\Windows` as before, but this is (after the reboot) *hopefully* the previous drive, from which you started. To make sure it all went according to plan, see if `C:\NEW-Windows.txt` is there, because then you confirmed that it's the new drive that has been booted.

To double-check that not only the Windows partition was transferred correctly, but also the boot loaders, temporarily disconnect the old drive (always while the computer is powered down!) and reboot. If everything works correctly without the old drive, you can reconnect it (again, while powered down). Once this is done, you can “re-initialize”, means format ;-), the old drive and reuse it for something else. I recommend [starting Disk Management](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-disk-management-from-command-prompt-2626097) (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and select “Disk Management”) to re-format the old drive (delete all existing partitions), and make one big NTFS partition on it... And don't forget to delete the `NEW-Windows.txt` file from your cloned (now only) Windows installation, since you don't need it anymore.

Have fun!