# I don't have admin priviledges on WIN10 and need to reset pasw0rd

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, administrator

We have a local PC with preinstalled **Windows 10**, and we want to use a program which requires some files to be copied to system32.

It's not possible because it requires administrator privileges which we don't have. We only have standard user account.

I tried all the options I could find on the internet Using Windows installation disc, trying to call prompt on login screen, trying with SAM, but nothing worked. It looks totally locked.

Utilman, CMD, sethc, don't work at all. I can't produce command prompt on login. I can't enable administrator built in account as I don't have permission.

Seems like there's no way to find or change the admin password. It's rather strange, considering it is so easy to reset root password in Linux, while here you are sitting in front of Windows desktop and can't do a thing.

I just want to make things easier, and I hope someone had similar experience with this

Comment: No files should be copied into `%WinDir%\System32` and I'm unsure how such information was stumbled upon. `%WinDir%` and its subfolders/files _(excl. `\etc\..`)_ should never be user-modified for two reasons: (1) Changes will be overwritten once `Sfc` is [run](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800); (2) there's literally no reason to copy anything into it/subdirectories. What exactly are you trying to accomplish, as no legitimate program will copy files into `%WinDir%\System32` _(that's what `%ProgramFiles%`, `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`, `%ProgramData%`, `%AppData%`, & `%LocalAppData%` are for)_?

Comment: You don’t actually need elevated permissions to enable the built-in Administrator account

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to have a look at this.
https://www.hirensbootcd.org/

I used this tool multiple times to enable the default Administrator or to remove the Password of the current local admin. I remember using both the non GUI and the GUI version of this.

On the GUI version you need to use NTPWEdit under Security > Passwords.
It's pretty self explanatory.

After you are done, please disable the default Administrator or set a password to the local admin account for security.

Also only use this if nobody in your company has the admin login credentials or a way of getting access to it. Not that it's forbidden but it should be considered as a last resort.

Also I recommend to be sure that you need to put anything into the system32 folder since it could be any other location and just needs to be coded into whatever program it is you guys are using.

Comment: **There is no legitimate program that installs files into `%WinDir%`** for two reasons: **(1)** Changes will be overwritten once [`Sfc`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sfc) is [run](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800); **(2)** there's literally no legitimate reason to copy anything into it or its subdirectories & no legitimate program will copy files into `%WinDir%\System32`  _(malware may do so, but no legitimate program will)_ as that's what `%ProgramFiles%`, `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`, `%ProgramData%`, `%AppData%`, and `%LocalAppData%` are for

Comment: WinDir is the last choice destination for installing programs and also as a temp folder. This is because running Win 3.1 from network it was the only location the user was guaranteed to be able to write to as WinDir is always on the local hard disk.