# Automatic Repair loop still in safe mode

Tags: windows-10, boot

My Windows stuck at Automatic Repair loop when ever I restart it's goes here and give failed blue screen with advanced troubleshoot button.

I also try regback but here it's empty.
I also try bootrec but no help.
I also try to goes on safe boot but same loop occur.
I also try chkdsk but it takes so much type and I cannot wait for a such time.

I Want to recover windows without removing my data especially program data?

any help will be appreciated.
I have Linux (Ubuntu) and Windows USB if it can also help.

Log Details:

```
Startup Repair diagnosis and repair log
---------------------------
Last successful boot time: ‎8/‎14/‎2021 2:49:39 PM (GMT)
Number of repair attempts: 22

Session details
---------------------------
System Disk = \Device\Harddisk0
Windows directory = C:\Windows
AutoChk Run = 0
Number of root causes = 1

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Check for updates
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: System disk test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Disk failure diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 219 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Disk metadata test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Disk metadata test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 16 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Target OS test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 156 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Volume content check
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 16953 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Boot manager diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: System boot log diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Event log diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 2750 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Internal state check
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 94 ms

Root cause found: 
---------------------------
Startup Repair has tried several times but still cannot determine the cause of the problem.

---------------------------
---------------------------
Session details
---------------------------
System Disk = \Device\Harddisk0
Windows directory = C:\Windows
AutoChk Run = 0
Number of root causes = 1

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Check for updates
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: System disk test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Disk failure diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 266 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Disk metadata test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Disk metadata test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 16 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Target OS test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 172 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Volume content check
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 28312 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Boot manager diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: System boot log diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Event log diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 2031 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Internal state check
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 94 ms

Root cause found: 
---------------------------
Startup Repair has tried several times but still cannot determine the cause of the problem.

---------------------------
---------------------------
Session details
---------------------------
System Disk = \Device\Harddisk0
Windows directory = C:\Windows
AutoChk Run = 0
Number of root causes = 0

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Check for updates
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: System disk test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 16 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Disk failure diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 1328 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Disk metadata test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 15 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Disk metadata test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 1610 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Target OS test
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 7078 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Volume content check
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 23953 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Boot manager diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 78 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: System boot log diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 31 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Event log diagnosis
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 2125 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Internal state check
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 79 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Check for installed LCU
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 1031 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Check for installed driver updates
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0
Time taken = 31 ms

Test Performed: 
---------------------------
Name: Check for pending package install
Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x2
Time taken = 16844 ms

---------------------------
---------------------------
```

Comment: When Automatic Repair fails to fix something, it provides the location of the log file - please review the log file and if unable to determine the issue, please post the log file within a code box. To access the log file, go back into the WinRE command prompt: `notepad` → `Ctrl`+`O` → `X:\Windows\System32\Logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt`. You can also try System Restore by issuing `rstrui` in the terminal

Comment: Try the fixes in [this article](https://www.technology.org/2017/11/14/7-ways-fix-stuck-in-windows-automatic-repair-loop/) and report on the results. You will need a Windows installation media or Recovery Drive/System Repair Disc. Good luck.

Comment: Log detail edit @JW0914

Comment: @harrymc try almost all

Comment: @Mohsin I would recommend running `ChkDsk` on the OS partition since you can't do so while booted to Windows anyway, but you'll need to determine the drive letter of the OS partition first since it's usually not `C:` in WinRE: `DiskPart` → `lis vol` → `exit` → `ChkDsk <OSpartition>: /OfflineScanAndFix` → Once done, either try Method #5 in the link harrymc provided, or use System Restore to restore to a prior date via `rstrui`, and once booted back to Windows, perform Steps 1 - 6 in [this](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) answer, then re-enable Automatic Repair.

Comment: _(Cont'd)_ Don't use Linux to repair Windows, as WinPE/WinRE contains all tools needed to fix a boot issue _(f dual-booting Windows and Linux **and** the BCD Store needs to be rebuilt, use Linux since `BootRec` will overwrite GRUB)_ - you can try `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD` _(UEFI: remove `&& BootRec /FixBoot`)_,. If performing Method #5, it's a temporary band-aid, not a solution, since it disables WinRE _(if Windows won't boot, boot Windows install USB and open terminal via `Shift`+`F10`)_.

Comment: Method 5 won't work same issue, now I start chkdsk, let see what happened?

Comment: @Mohsin Assuming no changes were made to the BIOS/UEFI firmware, it's either a filesystem issue or corrupted system files; the latter is a bit more complex if the `BootRec` commands [above] didn't fix the issue - in the WinPE terminal: `Sfc /ScanNow`, but this may not resolve the issue if the Component Store [OS partition: `%WinDir%\WinSxS`] or it's dirty or has corruption, which is why `Dism` should be run prior to `Sfc` [above link to Steps 1 - 6]; however, something changed a few years ago in Win10 and I haven't figured out the correct `Dism` command yet for running it from WinPE/WinRE yet.

Comment: Try to disable secure boot in the BIOS, then boot into the Command Prompt and enter the command `BCDEDIT /set nointegritychecks ON`. Then try to reboot normally.

Comment: @JW0914 after Chkdsk I get this error

Comment: error 0xc0000255

Comment: Your PC/Device need to be repaired
The OS system could not be loaded because the system registry missing or contain error.

Comment: There is no option for secure boot in BIOS

Comment: @Mohsin _(Please do not multi-post comments when not exceeding the character limit, instead please edit the previous comment, or if the 5min has expired and no one has commented afterward, please copy/paste the content into a new comment and delete the old, as comments aren't a [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=superuser.com) thread)_ Are you certain error `0xc0000255` was from `ChkDsk`, as that doesn't appear to be a valid error code for `ChkDsk` from search results returned on Microsoft Docs, DuckDuckGo, or an advanced search on Google

Comment: After running, chkdsk and restart PC, I stuck here now, what should I do now?