# How to solve "can not find script file "c:\windows\system32\c"

Tags: script, windows-11

recently this message keeps appearing "can not find script file "c:\windows\system32\c".
and when it appears (every minute or so if I closed it) it's always six of them together (as in the screenshots).
I have windows 11 installed.

Solutions I tried:

- Scanned my device with several Antiviurs programs, but nothing was found.
- Used "Microsoft defender" offline scan.
- Googled the problem and tried "Maintenance.vbs" and similar solutions, but nothing.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot of error message]

[image: How many messages I get each time]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: @harrymc I had a lot of misconception about malware and this was really helpful, thanks.

Comment: Issue is likely a task or script with a typo within a path in the script, likely a whitespace if not malware-related. `%WinDir%` and its subdirectories contain no user modifiable files, excluding files within `%WinDir%\System32\drivers\etc`. If booting from a LiveUSB and running an antivirus & anti-malware scan finds nothing, to resolve the issue the offending task or script would need to be found and modified - but it wouldn't be within `%WinDir%`. The only method for correcting corruption within `%WinDir%` is using `Dism`, then `Sfc` via [Steps 1 - 6](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800).

Answer (score 2):

There is (normally) no "C" folder or file in System32 in Windows 11. (I have 2 Production Windows 11 Pro systems here).

Use Windows Defender here.

Open the Security Center, Virus and Threat Protection.

Run a full scan.  Takes a while.

When done, go back to Scan Options and run select Microsoft Defender AntiVirus (offline scan) and run an offline scan.  When you select this, you will need to restart for the offline scan to run.

The two scans together should eliminate any viruses.

If, when done, you still have issues, back everything up and reinstall Windows 11.

Comment: I did the scan again and it found nothing. I think i'll have to reinstall windows. thanks for your answer.

Comment: That was my final point, so perhaps you might wish to acknowledge my answer