# I have strange 10gb file named d.sys in my windows folder what is it?

Tags: windows-10

there is a very strange large 10 GB file inside my Windows folder named "d". This file was created around 9 days ago. I can't delete or move that file. Also, there is no information on this file on the internet I have searched a lot. attaching the screenshot of the file and location does anyone have any idea what that file is and which software created that? any clue? please

[image]

**Update:**

I have just found out that this file is being used by a process named   "system"  but if it is a system file I am wondering why it was just created 9 days ago and why it is 10GB in size. Isn't it suspicious?

[image]

Comment: I do not have any such file as this on any of my Windows machines. Tree Size will certainly show a 10 GB file.  Something you downloaded?  A different kind of backup?

Comment: This smells a bit like a VeraCrypt volume, or something along those lines. Can you open the file in HxD or some other hex editor? Do you have a `D:` drive? What does the d.sys file have under "Properties > Security"?

Comment: @John no I didn't download anything.

Comment: @u1686_grawity ,   I tried to open just now with HxD but it says file in use, this is not VeraCrypt volume,   and yes I have D drive.

when I try to see the properties--> security tab it is showing error as follows 
"The requested security information is either unavailable or can't be displayed"

Comment: You can access that file either by making a disk image with a tool such as Macrium Reflect and mounting the image, enabling access to restricted files, or by booting from USB, e.g., with Hirens's BootCD (https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) or an alternative (https://alternativeto.net/software/hiren39s-bootcd/) and opening in a hex editor. BTW, if VeraCrypt, it would not be locked if not mounted. Do an offline malware scan, if suspicious.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik sure I will try that and inform here the results really appreciate you all

Comment: Since that's _not_ an OS file, as the OS does not save any new files to `%WinDir%` beyond `.cab`, `.inf`, and `.msu` files in subdirectories within `%WinDir%\System32` _(AFAIK)_, and no software is ever configured to use `%WinDir%` _(if one does, it's been incorrectly coded by the developer and should not be used)_, please perform [Steps 1  - 6](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) _(excl. #3)_, which will fix that `%WinDir%` corruption. If you'd like to keep the file for further investigating, boot to WinRE, then copy the file to `C:\Users\Public`, which in WinRE will not be within `C:`