# Windows 10 0xc000021a error after booting from external Windows 11 USB flash

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, bsod, external-drive, portable-harddrive

I can't boot into Windows 10, it shows blue screen with `0xc000021a` error code. Then tries to autorestore, but fails. I tried to restore it from Windows 11 on USB drive with DISM, but it shows me an error `0x800f0801`, and in DISM log file I found a line where it failed to load ...\System32\config\SECURITY into registry key with error code `0x800703f1`. More details and logs are bellow.

I have an external SSD drive with Windows 11 installed on it. I usually plug it on different computers USB port, and boot from it to Windows 11. This time, after removing external SSD drive I, as usual, turned on computer to boot from computers internal drive Windows 10 OS. It booted as normal, but when I try to login with my password, nothing happened. Like I am clicking enter and password input gets cleared, but nothing happens. I tried several times, but it always cleared the input, without logging in. I decided to restart, hopping to solve the problem, but after restart it showed me a blue screen with an error code `0xc000021a`. Now I can't boot from Windows 10 that was installed on that computer. I don't even sure, that the problem was booting from external Windows 11, because I have tried it before, and everything was ok.

The logs for the commands:

```
C:\Windows\system32>dism /image:G:\ /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:wim:G:\install.wim:3

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.22000.653
Image Version: 10.0.19045.3324
Error: 0x800f0801
DISM failed. No operation was performed.
For more information, review the log file.
The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log

  >---------- C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log --------------
...
...
CBS    Failed to load offline \\?\G:\Windows\System32\config\SECURITY hive from '\\?\G:\Windows\System32\config\SECURITY' into registry key '{bf1a281b-ad7b-4476-ac95-f47682990ce7}G:/Windows/System32/config/SECURITY'. [HRESULT = 0x800703f1 - ERROR_BADDB]
CBS    Failed to load offline registry: {bf1a281b-ad7b-4476-ac95-f47682990ce7}G:/Windows/System32/config/SECURITY [HRESULT = 0x800703f1 - ERROR_BADDB]
CBS    Failed to load offline SECURITY hive. [HRESULT = 0x800703f1 - ERROR_BADDB]
...
...
```

```
$ sfc /scannow /offBootDir=G:\ /offWinDir=G:\Windows /offLogFile=G:\sfc-log2.txt

  >-----------sfc-log2.txt -------------  
  00000001 Shim considered [l:126]'\??\G:\Windows\Servicing\amd64_microsoft-windows- servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.3266_none_7e25389a7c7bcadb\wcp.dll' : got STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND  

  00000002 Shim considered [l:123]'\??\G:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.3266_none_7e25389a7c7bcadb\wcp.dll' : got STATUS_SUCCESS  

  00000001@2023/9/15:05:58:05.197 WcpInitialize: wcp.dll version 10.0.19041.3266 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue please?

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation for this error? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xc000021a--winlogin-fatal-error

Comment: @DavidMarshall I have tried a lot of possible solutions, but still can't boot into old OS

Comment: @ImIm Link provided  \[[Bug Check 0xC000021A: WINLOGON_FATAL_ERROR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xc000021a--winlogin-fatal-error)\] lists what the issue is and resolutions for that error code. | **Issue:** Winlogon process terminated unexpectedly |  **Cause:** Occurs when a user-mode subsystem, such as WinLogon or the CSRSS, has been fatally compromised and security can no longer be guaranteed. In response, the OS switches to kernel mode. Windows cannot run without WinLogon or CSRSS | **Fix:** It lists how to resolve

Comment: @ImIm _(Cont'd...)_ If none of the resolution steps listed fix the issue, please update your question with that info and any error messages encountered. You can service an offline Windows image by booting to another Windows OS, such as 11, and using `dism` and `sfc` to service it: `Dism /Image:D:\Windows /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` → `Dism /Image:D:\Windows /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` → `Sfc /ScanNow /OffBootDir=D:\ /OffWinDir=D:\Windows /OffLogFile=D:\sfc-log.txt`

Comment: @JW0914 I get the same errors one after another. I opened the Windows 10 Download folder from Windows 11 file explorer, could this be the reason why  Windows 10 gives a BSoD. Maybe accessing Windows 10 files from Windows 11 changed permissions, that's why Windows 10 can't boot?

Comment: @ImIm - Unless you were prompted to change permission on files the permissions were not changed. The reason Windows cannot boot is due to a corrupt system file. DISM and SFC can only do so much. Windows typically must be working enough for those tools to repair problems

Comment: @ImIm I forgot to provide info when trying to do this from another OS version _(see [2.3](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800))_ - you have to use an `install.wim`/`install.esd` from the InstallUSB for the version of Windows 10 installed, using that as the source for checking the Component Store for corruption via `/RestoreHealth` **(1)** Get the correct image index from the ESD/WIM _(usually `1` is Home, `6` is Pro)_: `Dism /Get-ImageInfo /Image:Z:\sources\install.esd` **(2)** `Dism /Image:G:\Windows /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:esd:"Z:\sources\install.esd":6 /LimitAccess`

Comment: @JW0914 thank you for your comments. I tried many possible variants of dism and sfc, googled a lot, can't figure it out...

Comment: You NEED to tell us, in the question, what you've researched and tried. Those are basic parts of what a good question will require.

Comment: @music2myear Thank you for your advise, I have changed the question a bit, hope someone can help me...