# Start Menu crashing after applying Intune-Policy - Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, crash, start-menu, intune

I am living in a domain environment as an admin. In the last few week a problem appeared which affects the functionality of the *Windows 11 Start Menu*.

When usual-/non-admin user log on to their accounts and try to open the start-menu, it will crash. Pressing the windows-button will spawn the related process (`StartMenuExperienceHost` or just `Start`) but exits right away. Under `Windows Logs\Application` this application error appears:

```xml
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" Guid="{a0e9b465-b939-57d7-b27d-95d8e925ff57}" />
    <EventID>1000</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-11-30T11:11:44.8723211Z" />
    <EventRecordID>2000</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="9852" ThreadID="9904" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>secret-computer-name.domain.com</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-1659004503-562591055-725345543-1625" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="AppName">RuntimeBroker.exe</Data>
    <Data Name="AppVersion">10.0.22621.2506</Data>
    <Data Name="AppTimeStamp">a20f9b3f</Data>
    <Data Name="ModuleName">windowsudk.shellcommon.dll</Data>
    <Data Name="ModuleVersion">10.0.22621.2506</Data>
    <Data Name="ModuleTimeStamp">78ce9ced</Data>
    <Data Name="ExceptionCode">c0000005</Data>
    <Data Name="FaultingOffset">000000000010f27d</Data>
    <Data Name="ProcessId">0x368</Data>
    <Data Name="ProcessCreationTime">0x1da237e00660983</Data>
    <Data Name="AppPath">C:\Windows\System32\RuntimeBroker.exe</Data>
    <Data Name="ModulePath">C:\windows\system32\windowsudk.shellcommon.dll</Data>
    <Data Name="IntegratorReportId">071e2f64-79b2-4b27-9d6f-f730fc97b665</Data>
    <Data Name="PackageFullName">Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_10.0.22621.2506_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy</Data>
    <Data Name="PackageRelativeAppId">runtimebroker07f4358a809ac99a64a67c1</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

So far, I already tried several fixes:

- Repair the system with:

  ```powershell
  sfc /scannow
  dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
  ```
- Reset the Start-Menu and Shell-Application (with admin-rights):

  ```powershell
  Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost* | Reset-AppxPackage
  Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost | Reset-AppxPackage
  ```
- Re-register all system apps:

  ```powershell
  Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers |Where-Object {$_.InstallLocation -like "*SystemApps*"} | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
  ```

My next take would be to replace `windowsudk.shellcommon.dll`.

Is there a solution to this kind of problem? Note that on every admin-account it works flawless, but if a non-admin logs on the problem occurs.

I customized the Start Menu with a block of JSON via an [Intune-Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/configuration/start/customize-and-export-start-layout?tabs=intune&pivots=windows-11#get-the-pinnedlist-json).

Comment: Does it happen while in Safe Mode?

Comment: Also run Windows 11 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.

Comment: The failing application is Runtime Broker which is related to the Microsoft Store. Try to [Re-Register Microsoft Store](https://www.makeuseof.com/reregister-microsoft-store-apps-windows/).

Comment: @John - A repair install seems like an overkill solution to a problem that can be fixed without reinstalling Windows.

Comment: Just a suggestion. A Repair Install with Keep Everything comes back the way one started with little effort.

Comment: @Ramhound even in safeboot the start menu won't open

Comment: `Sfc` and `Dism` are hierarchical and [must](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) be run in the correct order - `Sfc` should _never_ be run prior to `Dism`

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem was **permission-related**. The start-menu was crashing because usual domain-users haven't had access to some programms specified in the json.

You need to make sure that all paths you specify in the json, are not just accessible to you, the admin, but also to any other user which receives your policy.

The above log give us an hint with the line:

```
<Data Name="ExceptionCode">c0000005</Data>
```

which tells us about an [access-violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168982/exception-error-c0000005-in-vc).

Unfortunately I cannot give you the exact diff of both json-blocks for example-reasons, because I don't have permisson to the related intune-tenant anymore.