# What is the difference between C:\Users\Default and C:\Users\Default User folders?

Tags: windows, windows-10, default-profile

What is the difference between `C:\Users\Default` and `C:\Users\Default User` folders?

```powershell
PS $ & "$HOME/psh/dirsize.ps1" "C:\Users\Default"

  2.01 MiB


PS $ & "$HOME/psh/dirsize.ps1" "C:\Users\Default User"

  dir : Access to the path "C:\Users\Default User" is denied.
  At C:\Users\t2-sma\psh\dirsize.ps1:2 char:21
    + "{0:n2} MiB" -f ( ( dir $dirName -force -recurse | measure -property  ...
    +                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Users\Default User:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

  0.00 MiB
```

- Both `C:\Users\Default` and `C:\Users\Default User` exists :

  ```powershell
  PS $ dir "C:\Users" -Force | ? Name -like 'Default*'

    Directory: C:\Users

      Mode          LastWriteTime  Length  Name
      ----          -------------  ------  ----
      d-rh--   31/05/2023   10:58          Default
      d--hsl   07/12/2019   10:30          Default User
  ```
- `dir` says `C:\Users\Default User` is a junction, but surprisingly PowerShell says nothing:

  ```powershell
  $ dir /a "C:\Users" | findstr Default

    31/05/2023  09:58    <DIR>          Default
    07/12/2019  10:30    <JUNCTION>     Default User [C:\Users\Default]


  PS $ (gi "C:\Users\Default User\" -Force).LinkType
  ```

Comment: In a normally set up machine (Windows 10 and 11) there is no c:\users\Default Users.   Just c:\users\Default.  So you may have set up such a user or folder but it is something on your machine.

Comment: that that is not a common/normal folder, in a system controlled directory, plus your error message, I'm wondering if "c:\users\Default Users\" exists at all. can you show us a directory listing?

Comment: On my (fairly) new Windows 11 machine, `C:\Users\Default User` is a link to `C:\Users\Default`.  I’m 99% sure that I didn't create that. Note that it has the SYSTEM attribute set, so you won’t see it unless you enable display of such files.

Comment: `(gi 'C:\Users\Default User\' -Force).LinkType` should return [`Junction`](https://imgur.com/a/tadNRVp) - if OP's terminal does not, please perform [Steps 1 - 6](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 11, at least, `C:\Users\Default` is an actual directory. 
And `C:\Users\Default User` is a link to `C:\Users\Default`.

Comment: A bit more effort could have gone in to answering the difference between the two, such as the purpose of each