# Some Windows apps won't start

Tags: windows-11, windows-store-app, application-launch

Some apps won't start after 5 minutes from the booting.

Specs:

- 12th Gen Intel Core i5-1240P 1.70 GHz
- 16GB RAM, 64-bit OS, x-64-based processor
- OS: Windows 11 Pro 23H2 (build 22635.3140 )
- Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22686.1000.0
- Windows Insider Program

More details:

- Everything works well right after the booting.
- Approximately 5 minutes pass while I do whatever I need to do, the problem begins.
- Notepad (Windows basic app) won't start. Adobe Acrobat either. But MS Office apps work well.
- List of not-working apps: Notepad, Adobe Acrobat, VS Code, Samsung Device Care, Samsung Settings
- List of working apps: MS Office, Windows basic apps (Calculator, Clock, Mail, Movies & TV), Media Player, Pot Player, Web browsers (Chrome, Edge, ...), Python 3.11, Julia 1.9.2

I tried 'scannow' from the command prompt as [explained here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-apps-are-not-launching/da6d647d-1bcc-4b3b-b1d5-9001d19ad2c0) but it didn't help.

I think 'Fresh Start' may solve the problem but I have to install all the apps again, so I will keep it as a last thing to do. Is there any solution?

Comment: I suggest to [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html), which will preserve settings and apps.

Comment: If Repair Install with Keep Everything does not work, then the next step is to back everything up and do a fresh install of Windows.

Comment: The link referenced for `sfc` is [factually inaccurate](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) - `dism` [must](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e) be run prior to `sfc`

Comment: Ah! "Windows Insider Program..." you have found what appears to be a *bug* in a *beta* (https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2023/12/14/announcing-windows-11-insider-preview-build-22635-2915-beta-channel/) version of Windows. As an (unpaid) *beta* tester, you should report that issue to Microsoft for resolution, so that those wishing to use a **fully tested *Release* version** do not face such an issue.

Comment: The solution of discovering a bug in a build from 3 months ago is to install the current build, since it's not possible to downgrade your build without a clean install, the best bet would be to install 26052.1000 since that will become 24H2.  You could try upgrading to 22635.3140 but I wouldn't recommend it, in fact if you cannot self diagnostic most problems, I wouldn't recommend either build to be honest.