# Uninstalling a device in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, windows-registry

I have the devices below, but when I right-click uninstall in Device Manager, it uninstalls correctly, reappearing when I refresh the list of devices.

Is there a way to uninstall the device from the Registry or a Windows folder, and what would be the way to proceed in these cases?

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\BTH\MS_BTHPAN\6&3794408c&1&2
```

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: You have to tick the box at the bottom of the uninstall dialogue in Device Manager to delete the installation drivers/install files - if that tick box doesn't show, it's an OEM driver _(e.g. System OEM drivers that get installed to `%WinDir%\INF\Oem##.inf` with no uninstall program for them because they're not intended to ever be uninstalled because they're OEM drivers)_ and the only way to permanently remove that I know of would be clean install Windows/restore to a point prior to driver installation

Comment: I get a "warning: you are going to uninstall this emergency device" box which I click on to accept and it is uninstalled but when I go back to the device manager to reload it is still there.

Comment: That's an odd warning message for a BT personal area network adapter - please try redoing the uninstall by ticking the box to delete the install drivers, then reboot immediately afterwards. Rebooting shouldn't be necessary to fully remove the device from Device Manager since it shouldn't be able to be recognized again since the install drivers have been remove - if it's still there after ticking that box and a reboot, the install drivers aren't being removed for some reason

Comment: Nothing doesn't stop me, it keeps appearing, there is no way to delete it from the registry?

Comment: That's not how Device Manager works - it lists hardware devices that are installed by drivers and if it won't uninstall even with ticking the box to delete the install files, you can try a repair install of Windows, but you'll likely need to clean install Windows, as that's not normal behavior for a network adapter, nor is the error message you're getting a normal error that should be populating

Comment: How do I clean Windows files? I have done an `sfc /scannow` I don't know what else to do

Comment: `Sfc` doesn't do anything with drivers and hardware _(please see this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) for what it does)_, You can try a repair install of Windows, but I doubt that would resolve this - if it is an issue with Device Manager itself, it would, as the error message you're getting isn't normal. To do a repair install, download the Windows install ISO, extract it to a directory, then run Windows' `setup.exe` _while booted to Windows_. If that doesn't resolve it, backup your data and do a clean install