# How can I fix this error in the DISM log file?

Tags: windows, logging, dism, error-logging, winsxs

I want to repair a corrupted Windows installed on a hard disk through another PC.The wim file that I use as a source for repair was extracted from another wim file that contains several versions of Windows, and I actually extracted a version of Windows that matched version of my corrupted  Windows.
I received the following message in the log file of the DISM command, I want to know what it means? Does it refer to a corrupted file system? How should I fix this error?

Command used :

```
Dism /image:G:\ /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:H:\install.wim /LimitAccess /Logpath:H:\dism.log
```

Error message:

```
Warning CBS The alternate source path directory could not be accessed [HRESULT = 0x8007007b - ERROR_INVALID_NAME]
```

Comment: What was the DISM command that you used?

Comment: "Does it refer to a corrupted file system?" - No; It means the source directory couldn't be accessed.

Comment: Which directory does it say?
@Ramhound

Comment: Please add to your post the DISM command that you used.

Comment: Dism /image:C:\ /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:D:\install.wim /LimitAccess /Logpath:D:\dism.log 

@harrymc

Comment: @SEPEHR - "Which directory does it say?" - It would be "D:\install.wim"

Comment: are you sure?

@Ramhound

Comment: @SEPEHR What is the size of the `D:\install.wim` file?

Comment: The error might mean that `D:\install.wim` doesn't exist.

Comment: @SEPEHR - I am positive. Considering, the error message you received, "The alternate source path directory could not be accessed."

Comment: @ Andrew Morton - "What is the size of the D:\install.wim file?" - 3.28 GB

Comment: @Ramhound - Why can't the directory be accessed? How can I fix the problem?

Comment: @SEPEHR - It's likely a syntax problem. Why are you not editing your question? Why do you need to provide the windows image.  You should be able to use /Online.  What problem are you trying to resolve by running this command?

Comment: @Ramhound - What do you mean by "syntax problem"? 

I want to repair a corrupted Windows installed on a hard disk through another PC, that's why I don't use the online parameter.

Comment: Let’s start over: run dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:D:\install.wim, if that doesn’t work, then the path to the windows image file isn’t correct. Provide a screenshot of the folder that contains the file with the full path show.  This windows image is the mounted ISO I presume? Which means it’s a read only directory. [Edit] your question to include this information. It’s unfair but what I am asking for is very reasonable, asking what I mean by a “syntax problem” is frustrating since what I mean is crystal clear

Answer (score 0):

The command structure is [incorrect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-a-windows-repair-source#use-files-a-source) - correct command to repair the [Component Store](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/manage-the-component-store) [`Windows\WinSxS`] of an offline Windows image:

---

- *There's no need to export a WIM from a multi-index ESD/WIM, as the index number must be specified regardless*

  - *Doing so creates more problems than it solves since an `install.esd` is always <4GB due to its compression ratio being 33% more efficient than WIM's, whereas an `install.wim` will always be >4GB (an issue for an EFI bootable Install USB formatted as FAT32)*

---

1. Ascertain the ESD/WIM index numbers and version/build info via [`/Get-ImageInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#get-imageinfo):

   ```bash
   # Default install.<esd|wim> index numbers - Home: 1 | Pro: 6
     Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:"H:\install.<esd|wim>"

   # Verify version and build information:
     Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:"H:\install.<esd|wim>" /Index:#
   ```

   ```powershell
   PS $ Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:"E:\sources\install.esd"

     Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
     Version: 10.0.22621.2792

       Details for image : E:\sources\install.esd

         Index : 1
         Name : Windows 11 Home
         Description : Windows 11 Home
         Size : 16,168,829,996 bytes

         Index : 2
         Name : Windows 11 Home N
         Description : Windows 11 Home N
         Size : 15,506,889,019 bytes

         Index : 3
         Name : Windows 11 Home Single Language
         Description : Windows 11 Home Single Language
         Size : 16,153,401,297 bytes

         Index : 4
         Name : Windows 11 Education
         Description : Windows 11 Education
         Size : 16,463,631,301 bytes

         Index : 5
         Name : Windows 11 Education N
         Description : Windows 11 Education N
         Size : 15,808,633,936 bytes

         Index : 6
         Name : Windows 11 Pro
         Description : Windows 11 Pro
         Size : 16,479,089,353 bytes

         Index : 7
         Name : Windows 11 Pro N
         Description : Windows 11 Pro N
         Size : 15,810,170,147 bytes


   PS $ Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:"E:\sources\install.esd" /Index:1

      Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
      Version: 10.0.22621.2792

         Details for image : E:\sources\install.esd

            Index : 1
            Name : Windows 11 Home
            Description : Windows 11 Home
            Size : 16,168,829,996 bytes
            WIM Bootable : No
            Architecture : x64
            Hal : <undefined>
            Version : 10.0.22621
            ServicePack Build : 525
            ServicePack Level : 0
            Edition : Core
            Installation : Client
            ProductType : WinNT
            ProductSuite : Terminal Server
            System Root : WINDOWS
            Directories : 22687
            Files : 102254
            Created : 2022.09.24 - 20:47:30
            Modified : 2022.11.11 - 07:04:21
            Languages : en-US (Default)


   PS $ Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:"E:\sources\install.esd" /Index:6

      Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
      Version: 10.0.22621.2792

         Details for image : E:\sources\install.esd

           Index : 6
           Name : Windows 11 Pro
           Description : Windows 11 Pro
           Size : 16,479,089,353 bytes
           WIM Bootable : No
           Architecture : x64
           Hal : <undefined>
           Version : 10.0.22621
           ServicePack Build : 525
           ServicePack Level : 0
           Edition : Professional
           Installation : Client
           ProductType : WinNT
           ProductSuite : Terminal Server
           System Root : WINDOWS
           Directories : 22867
           Files : 103384
           Created : 2022.09.24 - 20:47:30
           Modified : 2022.11.11 - 07:04:29
           Languages : en-US (Default)
   ```
2. [`/Cleanup-Image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-operating-system-package-servicing-command-line-options#cleanup-image) has a hierarchical order, so first run [`/StartComponentCleanup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder) to [clean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder) the Component Store of any broken [hard links](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/manage-the-component-store#hard-links), then run [`/RestoreHealth`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/repair-a-windows-image):

   ```powershell
   # Clean the offline image's Component Store:
     Dism /Image:"G:\Windows" /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup

   # Specify the index number at the end of the /Source parameter:
     # ESD:
       Dism /Image:"G:\Windows" /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:esd:"H:\install.esd":1 /LimitAccess /Logpath:"H:\dism.log"

     # WIM:
       Dism /Image:"G:\Windows" /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:"H:\install.wim":1 /LimitAccess /Logpath:"H:\dism.log"
   ```

   - While the OP mentioned this in their question, the `/Source` *must* match the exact version [23H2, 24H1, etc.] of the offline Windows image being repaired *(I'm unsure if the build version must also match)*
3. Once `/Cleanup-Image` has successfully completed its repair of the Component Store, [`Sfc /ScanNow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sfc) must also be run against the offline image to repair the OS files *(`/Cleanup-Image` and `/ScanNow` are inextricably [linked](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800))*:

   ```powershell
   # Repair offline Windows image OS files:
     Sfc /ScanNow /OffBootDir=G:\ /OffWinDir=G:\Windows /OffLogFile=H:\sfc.log

   # Export repair details to seperate log for efficient viewing:
     FindStr /c:"[SR]" "H:\sfc.log" > "H:\SFCdetails.log"
   ```

   <sup>*(Log files are easier to read and sift through via the [Log syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30776845/6819406) in [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/))*</sup>

Comment: "Dism /Image:G:\Windows /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:H:\install.wim:1 /LimitAccess /Logpath:H:\dism.log"

I ran this command and it gave this error :

"Unable to access the image.
Make sure that the image path and the Windows directory for the image exist a
you have Read permissions on the folder."

Comment: @SEPEHR That's an ACL permissions issue - I'm assuming it's being run from an Admin terminal? Try using the original `install.esd`, and if it's still giving the error, extract the Component Store [`Windows\WinSxS`] from the correct `install.<esd|wim>` index and change to `/Source:"H:\Windows\WinSxS"` to see if it still gives the error from and Admin terminal

Comment: @ JW0914 - As you said, I extracted "Windows\WinSxS" to C: drive and ran this command: [Dism /Image:G:\Windows /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:C:\New Folder\Windows\ WinSxS /LimitAccess /Logpath:H:\dism.log] and gave this error: [DISM doesn't recognize the command-line option "Folder\Windows\WinSxS".]

Comment: Hes quoting source, maybe you should too ;) /Source:"C:\New Folder\Windows\WinSxS"

Comment: @SEPEHR If that does not resolve, please copy/paste all terminal content and the `%WinDir%\Logs\DISM\dism.log` and `%WinDir%\Logs\CBS\cbs.log` into separate code boxes within your question. This answer and its commands are pulled directly from the linked to man pages _(the same content can be output with `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /?` - I'm unsure if `Dism /Image:G:\Windows /Cleanup-Image /?` will result in the help being displayed)_