# No boot entry and can't enter safe mode (but otherwise the system boots - Windows 10), how to fix the boot record?

Tags: windows-10, boot, safe-mode

When I need to enter safe mode with my Windows 10 system (2004 build 19041) I found out that I cannot as the only item available in the advanced boot menu is UEFI settings.

I think this is why:
[image]

But the system does boot fine! Is there a way to restore the boot record and regain access to safe mode?

If you're wondering why the system is so old - first of all, I have no incentive to update while it's working fine, but more importantly, it cannot update. And now I wonder whether that could also be because of the missing boot record.

Comment: Have you tried booting to WinRE Command Prompt and executing: `BootRec /FixMbr && BootRec /RebuildBcd`? "_I have no incentive to update while it's working fine_" - That's not why you update OSes; updates contain security patches, among other patches, and when a security patch is released for Windows, it shows how to exploit unpatched systems. Please update your OS - there's zero reasons for not allowing Windows Update to auto run and auto install updates on machines outside of a business running customized software and setups.

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks, will try. As I said, this system fails to update, it gets stuck in a loop and eventually updates get reverted (kudos to MS for actually implementing rollback and leaving the system in a functional state). But forced automatic updates are are as much a problem as they are an improvement. Updates that make your system slower or bloated are a problem.

Comment: Windows Update issues can often be fixed by following [Steps 1, 2, & 4](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) _(if issues persist, run the Windows Update Troubleshooter)_, however since your OS is 4yrs out of date, it would be far more efficient to do a Repair Install, which should also fix the boot options issue. For a Repair Install, download the Windows install ISO via the Media Creation Tool, extract the ISO to a directory _(preferably other than `C:`)_, then run `Setup.exe` while booted to Windows, choosing to Keep All Files and Settings.

Comment: @JW0914: that is a very interesting thing and I never knew such an option exists. Thanks, might come in handy. Unfortunately, in my case the installer only runs for some 10-15 seconds as says "having trouble determining if your PC can run Windows 10".

Answer (score 2):

You wish to update Windows 10 but your system is in a strange state, and
you get strange errors and updates are rollback. Not to mention that
you might have a boot problem.

I suggest to do the updates and at the same time bring Windows to a
known state, by following the article
[How to Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

This operation will update Windows 10 to its latest version.
Take backups of your data before starting.

Just to note that Windows 10 is approaching its end of life,
so you should really update to Windows 11 if your computer is
eligible, whenever Windows 10 is updated and again able
to do updates.

Check also for a BIOS update at your manufacturer's website
(do not download from any other website)
and apply it with care.