# CMD/Powershell looking for "curl" executable in the wrong location despite PATH

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, curl

I have a strange issue with both CMD and Powershell on Windows 10 that has been giving me some trouble. An unrelated scriptwas failing when running `curl`, and after some investigation it looks like a CMD and Powershell issue.

When I run `curl` in CMD, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\****>curl
Cannot find file at '..\\lib\curl\tools\curl-8.6.0_1-win64-mingw\bin\curl.exe' (C:\WINDOWS\lib\curl\tools\curl-8.6.0_1-win64-mingw\bin\curl.exe). This usually indicates a missing or moved file.
```

The same happens in PowerShell, though in that case I have to write `curl.exe` (plain `curl` aliases to `Invoke-WebRequest`).

This path does not exist. It is not present in PATH (or any other environment variable), either, and I can't figure out why CMD/Powershell is trying to look for `curl` there. I have tried putting `C:\Windows\System32` (where `curl` is actually located) at the beginning of PATH, but this didn't work.

Confusingly, `where` works just fine and doesn't show anything weird:

```
C:\Users\****>where curl
C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe
```

Any help is appreciated, let me know if I need to provide some more information.

Comment: Does running C:\windows\system32\curl.exe _with full path_ show the same message? Can you check whether `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\curl.exe` exists via regedit? The error message is definitely neither Cmd nor PS; you're somehow running a Chocolatey shim .exe (which _exists_ somewhere on your system, but its job is to run another .exe that doesn't exist).

Comment: Please add your entire PATH to your post.

Comment: @u1686_grawity Oh that's definitely it. I recall replacing the default curl with that but I had no idea it did that. The eternal curse of doing something stupid while trying to solve a tech problem. I'll replace it with an actual curl executable.

Comment: **Nothing should ever be installed to `%WinDir%`** - that is _never_ the way to install software _(except for driver installations and the handful of user modifiable config files within `%WinDir%\System32\drivers\etc`, `%WinDir%` is off-limits for modifications - [this](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) explains why)_. There are five default locations for installing software: `%ProgramFiles%`, `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`, `%ProgramData%`, `%LocalAppData%`, and `%AppData%`. If Chocolatey has been installed, or is installing software, to `%WinDir%`, it's configured incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, it is indeed running curl in the correct location, but the executable is a Chocolatey shim which tries to defer to another one.

For some reason I had manually replaced the `curl` inside `System32` with such an .exe to solve a different issue (which is as stupid as it sounds, I know). I re-replaced it with an actual `curl` executable and it works perfectly now.

Comment: This is an incomplete answer: "_I had manually replaced `curl` with such an `.exe` to solve a different issue..._" Manually replaced what `curl.exe`? | "_I re-replaced it with an actual `curl` executable..._" Replaced what `curl.exe` _(nothing should ever be installed to `%WinDir%` - that is **not** the way to install anything, as it will get overwritten by `sfc /scannow`)_?